# Path to current file depends on how I execute the program

Tags: python, path

This is my Python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

BASE_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
print BASE_PATH
```

If I run this using `python myfile.py` it prints an empty string. If I run it using `myfile.py`, it prints the correct path. Why is this? I'm using Windows Vista and Python 2.6.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just a harmless windows quirk; you can compensate by using `os.path.abspath(__file__)`, see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.abspath)

Comment: Do I use `abspath` only if I'm on Windows or do I use it regardless?

Comment: I'd probably use it regardless.

Comment: I'd use it everywhere if you want the absolute path (instead of relative to current directory).

Comment: @Alex, with os.path.abspath(__file__), python -m cProfile myfile.py return "C:\Python25\lib\cProfile.py" (or "/usr/lib/python2.5/cProfile.py")...

Comment: @sunqiang, that's what the OP asked for, right? The absolute path to the main file (and the -m is telling Python that the main file is cProfile.py, of course).

Comment: @Alex, yes, abspath is nice for OP's question. Just met this myself last time. The script is work but Profile it surprised me.

Comment: @sunqiang, maybe you weren't aware that cProfile.main uses execfile on the foo.py you're passing on the commandline -- `run('execfile(%r)' % (sys.argv[0],), options.outfile, options.sort)` is the key statement, a few lines from the end of cProfile.py.

Comment: @Alex, I see, now it doesn't surprised anymore, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In many cases it's better to use:

```
os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
```