# Find the current directory and file's directory

Tags: python, directory

How do I determine:

1. the current directory (where I was in the shell when I ran the Python script), and
2. where the Python file I am executing is?

Comment: `import os
cwd = os.getcwd()` to pwd within python

Comment: This question is **blatantly** two questions in one and should have been closed as needing more focus. Both questions are simple reference questions, and thus ought to each have separate canonicals that this can be dupe-hammered with. However, I have been absolutely tearing my hair out trying to find a **proper** canonical for **only** the first question. I am turning up **countless** duplicates for the second question, most of which involve OP **not realizing there is a difference**.

Comment: I have added the best I could find for "Q. How do I determine the current directory? A. Use `os.getcwd()`" after **literally hours** of searching. Ugh.

Comment: if you are just trying to get the current folder name without full path then you can try this :
`os.path.basename(<path>)`

Answer (score 4668, accepted):

To get the full path to the directory a Python file is contained in, write this in that file:

```
import os 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

(Note that the incantation above won't work if you've already used `os.chdir()` to change your current working directory, since the value of the `__file__` constant is relative to the current working directory and is not changed by an `os.chdir()` call.)

---

To get the current working directory use

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
```

---

Documentation references for the modules, constants and functions used above:

- The [`os`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html) and [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) modules.
- The [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) constant
- [`os.path.realpath(path)`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) (returns *"the canonical path of the specified filename, eliminating any symbolic links encountered in the path"*)
- [`os.path.dirname(path)`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) (returns *"the directory name of pathname `path`"*)
- [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getcwd) (returns *"a string representing the current working directory"*)
- [`os.chdir(path)`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir) (*"change the current working directory to `path`"*)

Comment: I hate it when I use this to append to sys.path.  I feel so dirty right now.

Comment: __file__ will not work if invoked from an IDE (say IDLE).
Suggest os.path.realpath('./') or 
os.getcwd(). Best anser in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python?lq=1

Comment: @Neon22 might suit some needs, but I feel it should be noted that those things aren't the same at all - files can be outside the working directory.

Comment: What about reversing the order, does it matter? `os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

Comment: @Moberg Often the paths will be the same when reversing `realpath` with `dirname`, but it will differ when the file (or its directory) is actually a symbolic link.

Comment: It gets an error `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`. How to solve this?

Comment: Apparently prepending to `sys.path` is acceptable according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

Comment: In some versions of python 2 (mainly windows versions) paths that include utf-8 characters (like emojis) will return with two question marks replacing the character from os functions, messing up any further commands that you try.

Comment: @RusselDias why do you put `realpath` inside `dirname`? I tested each independently and they work like charm!

Comment: @MohammadElNesr are you sure that you're using `os.path.realpath` and not `os.path.abspath`? you're error eften occurs with `abspath`.

Comment: for jupyter notebooks - try os.path.realpath(os.getcwd()) (when you're in the right working directory)

Comment: `os.path.dirname(__file__)` do the same that `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` in my code

Comment: Just make sure you use `"__file__"`

Comment: I don't think the first parenthesis is correct at all. `__file__` seems to be absolute, not relative to the CWD

Answer (score 384):

[Current working directory](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Working-Directory.html):  [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd)

And the [`__file__` attribute](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) can help you find out where the file you are executing is located. This Stack Overflow post explains everything:  *[How do I get the path of the current executed file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python)*

Answer (score 362):

You may find this useful as a reference:

```
import os

print("Path at terminal when executing this file")
print(os.getcwd() + "\n")

print("This file path, relative to os.getcwd()")
print(__file__ + "\n")

print("This file full path (following symlinks)")
full_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
print(full_path + "\n")

print("This file directory and name")
path, filename = os.path.split(full_path)
print(path + ' --> ' + filename + "\n")

print("This file directory only")
print(os.path.dirname(full_path))
```

Comment: what does `__file__` signifies here? It does not work for me.

Comment: The `__file__` is an attribute of the module object. You need run the code inside a Python file, not on the REPL.

Answer (score 304):

The [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module, [introduced in Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#pathlib) (*[PEP 428 — The pathlib module — object-oriented filesystem paths](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0428/)*), makes the path-related experience much much better.

```
pwd

/home/skovorodkin/stack

tree

.
└── scripts
    ├── 1.py
    └── 2.py
```

In order to get the current working directory, use [`Path.cwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.cwd):

```
from pathlib import Path

print(Path.cwd())  # /home/skovorodkin/stack
```

To get an absolute path to your script file, use the [`Path.resolve()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) method:

```
print(Path(__file__).resolve())  # /home/skovorodkin/stack/scripts/1.py
```

And to get the path of a directory where your script is located, access [`.parent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent) (it is recommended to call `.resolve()` before `.parent`):

```
print(Path(__file__).resolve().parent)  # /home/skovorodkin/stack/scripts
```

Remember that `__file__` is not reliable in some situations: *[How do I get the path of the current executed file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python)*.

---

Please note, that `Path.cwd()`, `Path.resolve()` and other `Path` methods return path objects ([`PosixPath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PosixPath) in my case), not strings. In Python 3.4 and 3.5 that caused some pain, because [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open) built-in function could only work with string or bytes objects, and did not support `Path` objects, so you had to convert `Path` objects to strings or use the [`Path.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open) method, but the latter option required you to change old code:

### File *scripts/2.py*

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(__file__).resolve()

with p.open() as f: pass
with open(str(p)) as f: pass
with open(p) as f: pass

print('OK')
```

#### Output

```
python3.5 scripts/2.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/2.py", line 11, in <module>
    with open(p) as f:
TypeError: invalid file: PosixPath('/home/skovorodkin/stack/scripts/2.py')
```

As you can see, `open(p)` does not work with Python 3.5.

*[PEP 519 — Adding a file system path protocol](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0519/)*, implemented in Python 3.6, adds support of [`PathLike`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.PathLike) objects to the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function, so now you can pass `Path` objects to the `open` function directly:

```
python3.6 scripts/2.py

OK
```

Comment: Note also that these methods are chainable, so you can use `app_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent` as a parallel to `../../../` if you need to.

Comment: What system has executables (or the equivalent) by the name "`python3.5`" and "`python3.6`"? Ubuntu [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa) doesn't (at least not by default). It has executables by the name "`python3`" and "`python2`" (but not "`python`" - which causes [some things to break](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2019/12/08/arm-toolchain-ubuntu-19-04-black-magic-probe/#Python_blues_on_Ubuntu))

Comment: @PeterMortensen, thanks for the corrections. I don't remember if I actually had `python3.x` symlinks that time. Maybe I thought it would make snippets a bit clearer to the reader.

Answer (score 83):

1. To get the current directory full path

   ```
   >>import os
   >>print os.getcwd()
   ```

   Output: "C :\Users\admin\myfolder"
2. To get the current directory folder name alone

   ```
   >>import os
   >>str1=os.getcwd()
   >>str2=str1.split('\\')
   >>n=len(str2)
   >>print str2[n-1]
   ```

   Output: "myfolder"

Comment: better do it in one line, i think: `os.getcwd().split('\\')[-1]`

Comment: better to use os.sep rather than hardcode for Windows: os.getcwd().split(os.sep)[-1]

Comment: the problem with this approach is that if you execute the script from a different directory, you will get that directory's name instead of the scripts', which may not be what you want.

Comment: Right, the current directory which hosts your file may not be your CWD

Answer (score 60):

[Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pathlib.html) can be used this way to get the directory containing the current script:

```
import pathlib
filepath = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent
```

Comment: I like this solution. However can cause some Python 2.X issues.

Comment: For python 3.3 and earlier pathlib has to be installed

Comment: @Kimmo The only reason you should be working in Python 2 code is to convert it to Python 3.

Comment: @kagnirick agreed, but there are still people who don't. I write all my new stuff with formatted string literals (PEP 498) using Python 3.6 so that someone doesn't go and push them to Python2.

Comment: Note also that these methods are chainable, so you can use `app_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent` as a parallel to `../../../` if you need to.

Comment: when i run the code in jupyter notebook, it has the error: `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`, how to solve?

Answer (score 44):

If you are trying to find the current directory of the file you are currently in:

OS agnostic way:

```
dirname, filename = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Answer (score 39):

If you're using Python 3.4, there is the brand new higher-level `pathlib` module which allows you to conveniently call `pathlib.Path.cwd()` to get a `Path` object representing your current working directory, along with many other new features.

More info on this new API can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html).

Comment: For Python version < 3.4 you can use `pathlib2`: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/

Answer (score 39):

To get the current directory full path:

```py
os.path.realpath('.')
```

Comment: This one works from inside a jupyter iPython notebook (´__file__´ and getcwd won't)

Comment: Still valid. Thanks from the future @OliverZendel!

Comment: I'm working remotely with a Jupyter Notebook: `os.getcwd()` and `os.path.realpath('.') return exactly the same string path.

Comment: @Leevo: Point being?

Comment: This returns the jupyter root directory, not the directory holding the file.

Answer (score 35):

**Answer to #1:**

If you want the current directory, do this:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

If you want just any folder name and you have the path to that folder, do this:

```python
def get_folder_name(folder):
    '''
    Returns the folder name, given a full folder path
    '''
    return folder.split(os.sep)[-1]
```

**Answer to #2:**

```
import os
print os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

Answer (score 31):

I think the most succinct way to find just the name of your current execution context would be:

```
current_folder_path, current_folder_name = os.path.split(os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 18):

If you're searching for the location of the currently executed script, you can use `sys.argv[0]` to get the full path.

Comment: This is wrong. `sys.argv[0]` needn't contain the *full* path to the executing script.

Answer (score 18):

For question 1, use `os.getcwd() # Get working directory` and `os.chdir(r'D:\Steam\steamapps\common') # Set working directory`

---

I recommend using `sys.argv[0]` for question 2 because `sys.argv` is immutable and therefore always returns the current file (module object path) and not affected by `os.chdir()`. Also you can do like this:

```
import os
this_py_file = os.path.realpath(__file__)

# vvv Below comes your code vvv #
```

But that snippet and `sys.argv[0]` will not work or will work weird when compiled by PyInstaller, because magic properties are not set in `__main__` level and `sys.argv[0]` is the way your executable was called (it means that it becomes affected by the working directory).