# How to load data from a file, for a unit test, in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, file-io

I've written a specialized HTML parser, that I want to unit test with a couple of sample webpages I've downloaded.

In Java, I've used class resources, to load data into unit tests, without having to rely on them being at a particular path on the file system. Is there a way to do this in Python?

I found the [doctest.testfile()](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#doctest.testfile) function, but that appears to be specific to doctests. I'd like to just get a file handle, to a particular HTML file, which is relative to the current module.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 88, accepted):

To load data from a file in a unittest, if the testdata is on the same dir as unittests, one solution :

```
TESTDATA_FILENAME = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'testdata.html')


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase)

   def setUp(self):
       self.testdata = open(TESTDATA_FILENAME).read()

   def test_something(self):
       ....
```

Comment: Using the 'new' python [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) this command becomes: `TEST_FILE = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.joinpath("testdata.html")` and then `TEST_FILE.open()`. Remember to `import pathlib` and please note the suggestion in the answer from @LeilaHC to properly close the testfile again, e.g. in the tearDown method.

Comment: [`pkg_resources`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html) is a tool that comes with `setuptools`. If a package is installed, even with just `pip install -e` or `./setup.py develop`, then `pkg_resources` can find resource files just by knowing `__name__`.

Answer (score 24):

This is based on Ferran's answer, but it closes the file during `MyTest.tearDown()` to avoid 'ResourceWarning: unclosed file':

```
TESTDATA_FILENAME = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'testdata.html')


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase)

   def setUp(self):
       self.testfile = open(TESTDATA_FILENAME)
       self.testdata = self.testfile.read()

   def tearDown(self):
       self.testfile.close()

   def test_something(self):
       ....
```

Comment: For visibility, it might be better to edit Ferran's answer with your addition.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a StringIO or cStringIO to simulate a string containing your file's contents as a file.

Comment: Ya, I thought of that, but it would require that I put all the HTML into a python file as a string, which I don't like as it's > 3k lines long

Answer (score 1):

I guess your task boils down to what's given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory) to get the current file. Then extend that path by the path to you HTML file and [open](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) it.