# Selenium not connecting

Tags: python, unit-testing, sockets, selenium

Im trying to run some tests, and am running into a road block,

this is the start of the script where it is gettings caught.

```
from selenium import selenium
import subprocess
import time
import sys
import socket
from os.path import dirname
import unittest
from pushdata import push


class selenium_tests(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        directory = dirname(__file__)
        path = directory + '/selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar'
        sub = subprocess.Popen('exec java -jar ' + path,
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                               shell=True)
        self.selenium_server = sub
        count = 0
        while True:  # ensure the server is established
            try:
                self.selenium = selenium("localhost",
                                         4444,
                                         "*chrome",
                                         "http://127.0.0.1:8000/resources/")
                self.selenium.start()
                break
            except socket.error, v:
                count += 1
                if count == 10:
                    message = "- Selenium server took to long to establish"
                    print "\n", v, message
                    sys.exit()
                time.sleep(1)
```

To run the tests i am using the command:

```
python -m unittest -v selenium_tests_mod
```

which raises:

```
[Errno 111] Connection refused - Selenium server took to long to establish
```

so i know it is having trouble establishing the connection, just not why?

Note: when i run this using the django test framework it works, just not when i try to run it manually

EDIT:

when i run the selenium server in a seperate shell it works

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar
```

so now i am assuming this may be the cause:

```
sub = subprocess.Popen('exec java -jar ' + path,
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                               shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

worked out that

```
dirname(__file__)
```

was returning an empty string so searched around and found this: [Find current directory and file's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory)

so the answer as posted by Piotr Dobrogost, was to use

```
dirname(realpath(__file))
```