# Python: How to find current working directory in shell?

Tags: python

`os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` will find your current working directory, but if I'm running the python shell, `__file__` is undefined, so that method throws an exception.

How can you find your current working directory while inside a Python shell?

Running: Windows 7, Python 3.3, VirtualEnv

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find current directory and file's directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory)

Comment: That won't find your current working directory in a script either. It'll find the directory the script is in. So, for example, if I'm in `C:\Users\me`, and I run `C:\Python33\python D:\MyStuff\MyScript.py`, the current working directory is `C:\Users\me`, but you're going to get `D:\MyStuff`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd) function:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/univerio'
```