# problems with open file using relative path in python 3

Tags: python

I wrote a package for py 3 and have some problems:

```
Package
       __init__.py
       File.txt
       Run.py
               def run():
                      open ("File.txt")
```

Now I import `Run.py` in the console, but when I use `Run.run()`
it says that there is no file named `File.txt`.
Please help!

Comment: How exactly do you import it?

Comment: from Package import Run

Answer (score 2):

When you import a module/package, it does not change the working directory you are in. You can check this by using `import os` and then checking `os.getcwd()` before and after the import. Therefore, `open("File.txt")` looks for a file *in the current working directory*, which usually is the directory you were in on the shell before you started python. Example:

```
/a/b/c $ python
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
"/a/b/c"
>>> from Package import Run # import run.py
>>> os.getcwd()
"/a/b/c"
```

To find the directory the current file is in (which you want to do in `Run.py`), use

```
import os
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory). Then you can do

```
open(os.path.join(path, "File.txt"))
```

to open the right `File.txt`. Beware, however, that `__file__` only works in actual script files, so you can't use it in most IDEs and the interactive interpreter.