# get script directory name - Python

Tags: python, file, python-os, getcwd

I know I can use this to get the full file path

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

But I want just the name of the folder, my scrip is in. SO if I have my_script.py and it is located at

```
/home/user/test/my_script.py
```

I want to return "test" How could I do this?

Thanks

Comment: The answer is here. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
import os
os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

Broken down:

```
currentFile = __file__  # May be 'my_script', or './my_script' or
                        # '/home/user/test/my_script.py' depending on exactly how
                        # the script was run/loaded.
realPath = os.path.realpath(currentFile)  # /home/user/test/my_script.py
dirPath = os.path.dirname(realPath)  # /home/user/test
dirName = os.path.basename(dirPath) # test
```

Comment: +1 `os.path.basename(os.getcwd())` also works if you care only for the directory you run the script from.

Answer (score 50):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
```

Comment: That would return `/home/user/test/`, not `test`.

Comment: Actually, if you were to call your script from another directory (`cd /home/user; python test/my_script.py`) it will not even return that. It will return the directory that you are in (in the example: `/home/user/`)

Comment: @bytesized But the OP did ask to get *current working directory* which means the current directory that you are in when you ran the interpreter. So `os.getcwd` does exactly that.

Comment: @greatwolf To quote the OP, "But I want just the name of the folder, my scrip is in. SO if I have my_script.py and it is located at `/home/user/test/my_script.py` I want to return 'test'". Although the title of the question is "get current directory", that is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: this just returns current working directory. So whichever location you're calling your python script from is going to be returned. @greatwolf so yes, cwd() doesn't solve the issue because OP just wanted first level path of the parent directory and not everything starting all the way from root aka '/'

Comment: it is amazing how many wrong answers like this are floating around. op didn't ask for cwd

Answer (score -3):

Just write

```
import os
import os.path
print( os.path.basename(os.getcwd()) )
```

Hope this helps...