# Python how to start a program from current working directory

Tags: python, directory, cd, cwd

For example in batch (windows) you can use %CD%\ or .\ to start something from cwd but I dont know how to do it on python...

I tried`subprocess.call(['.\somedirectory\someprogram.exe'])` And `subprocess.call(['\\somedirectory\someprogram.exe'])`

edit:
Also the command I used in batch is: `start %CD%\somedirectory\someprogram.exe` or `start .\somedirectory\someprogram.exe`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find current directory and file's directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested it but this should work:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["start %CD%\somedirectory\someprogram.exe", "-l"])
```

However your filepath declaration seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: Did you mean 'os.system(start %CD%\somedirectory\someprogram.exe)' Because the command you suggested does not work. Note: im using python 3.5 and Im trying to make something all in python.