# Python script to run other scripts Problems with os.getcwd()

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python script to run other python scripts.

The problem is that the other scripts I am trying to run are in a diffrent directory. And in those other python scripts it uses the `os.getcwd()` function as well.

When the other scripts runs, it gets the working directory path via `os.getcwd()` function. returns the current directory of the  first orgin script that executed the other scripts

Im running the like this:

```
os.system("python "+ os.getcwd()+r"\BDJCOMPUTERREPAIR\poster1-1.py")
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory

Comment: `os.getcwd()` is actually the directory from which you ran the first script. It is not necessarily the directory where even the first script is located. Also, look at `subprocess` module better ways to run separate processes.

Comment: Thank you very much Mad Physicist and thank you Goelakash.Geolakash the thing you mention does work but i need to edit alot of code. Thankyou for advice it was very helpul.