# IOError while reading files

Tags: python

From where does python pick its file for reading.Is there any specific 
folder,or does it pick from anywhere on the system just given the filename 
and extension.Is there a need to mention absolute path.
I am getting error while reading txt and csv files as no such file or directory. 
  f=open('info.csv')
  print f
I get a handle for the above file.But don't get a handle for .txt,both are in the 
same folder.Why does it give an error?

Comment: Your code? Your current output (error?)? Your expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find current directory and file's directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory)

Comment: code is very simple. f=open('info.txt')
print f the same works for f=open('fly.csv') print f both are in same folder.I get a handle for .csv whereas i don't get for .txt.

Answer (score 0):

By default, python checks for the requested file in the same directory the program file is in. If you want python to check for the file in some other location, you have to specify the absolute path.

About your error, nothing can be said unless you share your code.