# unotools - try to convert ods or excel files to csv using python

Tags: python, libreoffice, headless, uno, pyuno

What I need is a command line tool to convert excel and ods spreadsheet files to csv which I can use on a web server (Ubuntu 16.04).
I already red this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unotools
which works fine for the given examples.

And this: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/convert-spreadsheets-csv-files-python-and-pyuno-part-1v2
which should do the work I want it to do, but does not in my environment.

My problem I think is in the method Calc.store_to_url:

**Line throwing exception**

component.store_to_url(url,'FilterName','Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)')

I really would appreciate a hint.

**Exception**

unotools.unohelper.ErrorCodeIOException: SfxBaseModel::impl_store  failed: 0x81a

**Full source**

```
import sys
from os.path import basename, join as pathjoin, splitext

from unotools import Socket, connect
from unotools.component.calc import Calc
from unotools.unohelper import convert_path_to_url
from unotools import parse_argument



def get_component(args, context):
    _, ext = splitext(args.file_)
    url = convert_path_to_url(args.file_)
    component = Calc(context, url)
    return component

def convert_csv(args, context):
    component = get_component(args, context)
    url = 'out/result.csv'    
    component.store_to_url(url,'FilterName','Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)')
    component.close(True)


args = parse_argument(sys.argv[1:])
context = connect(Socket(args.host, args.port), option=args.option)

convert_csv(args, context)
```

Comment: which parameters are you passing to the `convert_csv()`?

Comment: full command is: python3 convert.py -s localhost -p 2002 -f excel.xlsx (host and port are checked and doing fine)

Comment: This question uses `unotools` rather than straight `pyuno`, so the title and tag are misleading.  However the issue is relevant to any code that uses the UNO interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL must be in `file://` format.

```
url = convert_path_to_url('out/result.csv')
```

See the `store_to_url` example at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unotools.

**EDIT**:

To use the absolute path, choose one of these; there is no need to combine them.

```
url = 'file:///home/me/out/result.csv'
url = convert_path_to_url('/home/me/out/result.csv')
```

To use the relative path, first verify that the working directory is '/home/me' by calling [os.getcwd()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5137509/5100564).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works fine but I had to use absolute path like: convert_path_to_url('file:///home/me/out/result.csv')