# How to use the current folder the program is in?

Tags: python

When I open a file, I have to specify the directory that it is in.  Is there a way to specify using the current directory instead of writing out the path name?  I'm using:

```
source = os.listdir("../mydirectory")
```

But the program will only work if it is placed in a directory called "mydirectory".  I want the program to work in the directory it is in, no matter what the name is.

```
def copyfiles(servername):

    source = os.listdir("../mydirectory") # directory where original configs are located
    destination = '//' + servername + r'/c$/remotedir/' # destination server directory
    for files in source:
        if files.endswith("myfile.config"):
            try:
                os.makedirs(destination, exist_ok=True)
                shutil.copy(files,destination)
            except:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find current directory and file's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'.'` stands for the current directory.

Comment: It's worth mentioning for the sake of completeness that if relative paths _somehow_ don't work, there's always `os.getcwd()`.

Answer (score 3):

this is a [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) version:

```
from pathlib import Path
HERE = Path(__file__).parent
source = list((HERE /  "../mydirectory").iterdir())
```

if you prefer [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname):

```
import os.path
HERE = os.path.dirname(__file__)
source = os.listdir(os.path.join(HERE, "../mydirectory"))
```

note: this will often be different from the current working directory

```
os.getcwd()  #  or '.'
```

[`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes) is the filename of your current python file. `HERE` is now the path of the directory where your python file lives.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
os.listdir('./')
```

or:

```
os.listdir(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you are using Python 3.x, you can simply use `os.listdir()` without any arguments. Also, the `/` is unnecessary :)