# Python: Opening a web page from file

Tags: python, file, web

I need to open a HTML page in the web browser using Python.
I am doing this with the `webbrowser` lib and `webbrowser.open(url, new = 2)` and actually it works pretty fine. But because I want to open the page from a file and I also want to export my project to other computers the URL is not always the same, according to where the user stored my project.
At the moment I am using this

```
url = r"file:///C:/Users/xyx/Desktop/Application/Main/TestApp/index-release.html"
```

But I need to do something like this:

```
url = r"file:///../Javascript/Main/TestApp/index-release.html"
```

With the dots for going a directory back(in what ever dir my application is stored and then into the afterwards given path. But if I do it like this, it does not work and just opens a **"about:blank"** page.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: perhaps look at this for getting your file path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to absolutize your path before creating the file URL. Something like:

```
import os

path = '../Javascript/Main/TestApp/index-release.html'
url = 'file:///' + os.path.abspath(path)
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you.