# In python, how do I get the full path name of "."?

Tags: python, directory, os.path

I tried with:

```
dir = os.path.dirname(".")
```

And the return is empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Find current directory and file's directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find current directory and file's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory)

Comment: `dirname` doesn't even look at the file system; it is purely a string operation on a file path that (roughly) drops the part after the last `/`.

Answer (score 4):

[`abspath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) should do the trick:

```
dir = os.path.abspath('.')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `abspath`:

```
dir = os.path.abspath('.')
```

or for the current working directory

```
dir = os.path.getcwd()
```