# python - proper and fail-safe way to open non py file from not current directory

Tags: python, file, cmd, import, pytest

What is the proper and fail-safe way to open non py file from not current directory?

---

To be more specific, I have a method, which validates API response with JSON schema, contained in file *schema.json*:

```
def foo():
    json_data = collect_json_data()
    schema = json.load(open('./schema/schema.json'))
    jsonschema.validate(json_data, schema)
```

And got the following project structure:

```
D:\projects\project-pytest\.  
│   .gitignore
│   LICENSE
│   README.md
│   requirenments.txt
│   runner_01.cmd
│   structure.txt
│   
├───tests
│   │   runner_02.cmd
│   │   file_with_tests.py
│   │     
│   ├───schema
│   │       schema.json
```

My goal is to run tests not only from the directory `project-pytest\tests\` by exectuting command `python -m pytest file_with_tests.py`, but also from parent directory, by executing `runner_01.cmd`, with command `python -m pytest -v .\tests\file_with_tests.py` inside.

Now the second way fails with `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './schema/schema.json'`.

I tried using `import os`:

```
schema_path = os.path.abspath('schema.json')  
schema = json.load(open(schema_path))
```

but in this case absolute path ignores `schema.json` parent directory - `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Git\\testarea-pytest\\schema.json'`.

---

How should I open my `schema.json` placed in different sub-directory and be able to run commands:
`python -m pytest -v .\tests\file_with_tests.py` from `project-pytest` folder
and
`python -m pytest -v file_with_tests.py` from `project-pytest\tests\` folder
without failing test because of `FileNotFoundError`.

Comment: Try and open your schema.json using the absolute path? You can find an absolute path when running any script using a solution like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory. So you can either hard code the path or find it by using the solution in the stackoverflow post.

Comment: @RobertMilletich my goal is exaclty to avoid any hardcode and make fail-safe solution.
I also tried trick `schema_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'schema', 'schema.json')`, but it outputs same error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Git\\testarea-pytest\\schema\\schema.json'`, if I run command from root project folder. However it works, if I run comand from ./tests/ folder. But I need solution, that fits both ways.

Comment: Your current working directory in the tests folder would be the tests folder, which is why the script works when you run it from that directory. What I would do it define the absolute path to schema.json at runtime. For example, when you run something like python (absolute path to) file_with_tests.py from any directory, you should be able to get the absolute path of the test directory using dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(\__file\__)). From here, define the absolute path to schema.json using path_to_json = os.path.join(dir_path, os.path.join('schema', 'schema.json')).

Comment: @RobertMilletich, I tried `schema_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname('schema.json'), 'schema', 'schema.json')`, and got same result as described above - `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Git\\testarea-pytest\\schema\\schema.json'`, if I run command from root project folder. However it works, if I run comand from `./tests/` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed problem to achieve my goals from the other side - I changed my `runner_01.cmd` from this:

```
python -m pytest -v file_with_tests.py
```

to this:

```
cd ./tests/
python -m pytest -v file_with_tests.py
```

Now tests can be runned from project folder and also from the tests folder by simple cmd script runners. Can't definetely say is this a kludge or not, but users are happy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy in making your project a package, `pkgutil.get_data()` can help abstracting from the resource location in the filesystem.

See [here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html?highlight=pkgutil%20get_data#pkgutil.get_data)