# Load different resources when testing in Python

Tags: java, python, testing, resources, classpath

First of all let me put you in context. My main background is Java and I'm working in Python since 2 months ago. I don't know if the approach it's wrong due to my Java background and in Python has a different solution or it's just a technical ignorance problem.

In Java often you have a packaging structure like:

```
project
   |___src
        |___main
        |     |___java/MyClass.java
        |     |___resources/properties.file 
        |
        |___test 
              |___java/MyClassTest.java
              |___resources/properties.file
```

Thus, when you execute this from tests (with Maven or IDE):

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
```

Either Maven or IDE loads the test path in the classpath, making test resources available rather than the ones within the main package. 
Conversely, when previous line is executed as main, only the resources within the main path are loaded to the classpath.

**My question is**: Is there any mechanism in Python to simulate this feature? Does Python have other ways to manage resources depending on the execution path?

Comment: So you want the class to behave differently when being tested vs. when it is being run without the test framework?

Comment: Not exactly, I want the same behavior. I just want to load the file from different folders depending on if it's run by tests or as "main"

Answer (score 2):

I think [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) might be what you are looking for.  It allows for 'mock'ing out external functions to limit the test to strictly the unit under test.

This could mean changing some of the philosophy around some of it.  For example, if you want to test that a function is reading a file correctly the filename would get passed to the method as a parameter.  In your unit test for the function, pass in a different filename from your test folder.

In another test `mock` out the `open` call to the os to check that the method responds as expected when the file is not there, or cannot be opened, or whatever other mis-behaviors you want to test for.

Comment: We've already considered this workaround, however, due to its increased complexity we though that there might exist another easier approach.

Comment: @PauTrepat  If your program is structured so that the determination of what file/folder to read is in its own function/method, then just `mock` out that function/method and tell `mock` to return the one that contains your test data.

Comment: Thanks! I know how to mock. But mocking implies coupling to implementation and coming from Java we thought maybe could exists an easy (and no coupling) way

Answer (score 0):

No, Python has no deployable like Java has (WAR, JAR, etc...). You will run your code directly from the source, so, just [read the file](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python).

In the Java context, you do not have the code when it is deployed. So every resource should be package inside a file ([JAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) or [WAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format))).

If you want to find the file in the current folder, look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory).

Comment: I think that the question is how to separate applicative source/resources from test source/resources.  Packaging doesn't have any relation with.

Comment: Sorry but I was actually wondering about any mechanisms to dynamically modify the classpath (or it's equivalent in Python) depending if the code is run by tests or as "main".

Comment: You can read the folder based on your environment. I believe this concept os **classpath** does not exists on Python.

Comment: @davidxxx, the folder structure of a Java project reflects the packaging method form Java. The question is about the differences from Java to Python

Comment: @Victor Not only the packaging. It reflects the build more generally and the build is not only the packaging of the application. It may be filtering resource, documentation generation, test executing and so for.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know very well Python but you are right to ask yourself the question 
as separating test and application code makes part of good practice to have a robust/reliable application and tests.

The `pytest` (a known test framework for Python) documentation explains in [its best practice guide](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html) the two ways (separating and not separating the test code from the application).
Here is the part referencing the isolated layout :

> **Choosing a test layout / import rules**
>
> pytest supports two common test layouts:
>
> **Tests outside application code**
>
> Putting tests into an extra directory outside your actual application
>   code might be useful if you have many functional tests or for other
>   reasons want to keep tests separate from actual application code
>   (often a good idea):
>
> ```
> setup.py
> mypkg/
>     init.py
>     app.py
>     view.py 
> tests/
>     test_app.py
>     test_view.py
>     ...
> ```
>
> This way your tests can run easily against an installed version of
>   mypkg.
>
> Note that using this scheme your test files must have unique names,
>   because pytest will import them as top-level modules since there are
>   no packages to derive a full package name from. In other words, the
>   test files in the example above will be imported as test_app and
>   test_view top-level modules by adding tests/ to sys.path.
>
> If you need to have test modules with the same name, you might add
>   **init**.py files to your tests folder and subfolders, changing them to packages:
>
> ```
> setup.py 
> mypkg/
>     ... 
> tests/
>     init.py
>     foo/
>         init.py
>         test_view.py
>     bar/
>         init.py
>         test_view.py
> ```
>
> Now pytest will load the modules as tests.foo.test_view and
>   tests.bar.test_view, allowing you to have modules with the same name.
>   But now this introduces a subtle problem: in order to load the test
>   modules from the tests directory, pytest prepends the root of the
>   repository to sys.path, which adds the side-effect that now mypkg is
>   also importable. This is problematic if you are using a tool like tox
>   to test your package in a virtual environment, because you want to
>   test the installed version of your package, not the local code from
>   the repository.
>
> In this situation, it is strongly suggested to use a src layout where
>   application root package resides in a sub-directory of your root:
>
> ```
> setup.py 
> src/
>     mypkg/
>         init.py
>         app.py
>         view.py 
> tests/
>     init.py
>     foo/
>         init.py
>         test_view.py
>     bar/
>         init.py
>         test_view.py
> ```
>
> This layout prevents a lot of common pitfalls and has many benefits, which are better explained in this
>   excellent blog post by Ionel Cristian Mărieș.
>
> https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html

Comment: This response does not mention anything about the a `/resources` option best practice in then python context.