# Set Working Directory and Read .csv with Variable Filename

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have some .csv files that I read into my code that could have a number of different names.

ex.

17159_output.csv
18001_output.csv

I read it in with pandas

```
d = pd.read_csv('17159_output.csv')
```

How can I write it so that it is something like %%%%%_output.csv

```
d = pd.read_csv('%%%%%_output.csv')
```

%%%%% will always be 5 digits

Comment: Do you know what the number is, or do you just want to read any file with that pattern? What if there are several?

Comment: you can iterate files in the directory with `os.listdir(directory)` and then concatenate the result

Comment: There will only be one and it will have that pattern so I want to read anything with that pattern

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Are you thinking you want to use regex? Are those `%` always going to be digits (numbers)? If you know there will only be one file that has a pattern, why do you want to read anything with that pattern since there's only going to be one?

Comment: Because I am going to make this an executable and it will be run in different directories. The file will always have that pattern but the 5 digits will be different.

Answer (score 1):

Just use simple [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for this.

```
d = pd.read_csv('{0}_output.csv'.format(17159)
```

Comment: What if I do not want to edit the code each time it is run? I just want it to find the .csv with that pattern.

Comment: Have a look at `os.listdir()` or `glob`.