# Python - Get the real path (location) of the source file where I'm coding

Tags: python, path

From here: [Find current directory and file's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory)

I tried in spyder (Python IDE):

```
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))
```

and:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
```

I only get like just the user directory and not the location of my source file where I'm coding

My source code is here:

> C:\Users\username\test\testerrr\test.py

I only get:

> C:\Users\username

I use:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))
```

and not:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

else I get this:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-98004a18344a>", line 1, in <module>
    os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

Well, it seems that's works only when we run its through shell.

Comment: So is the output you showed the value of `dir_path` or `cwd`? Why do you even retrieve the `cwd`?

Comment: `'__file__'` should be `__file__`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

not `'__file__'`. It should be `__file__`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes `'__file__'` should be `__file__`.

What you are getting from `os.path.realpath('__file__')` is  `$CWD/__file__` which is not what you want. That is why you get `$CWD` when you call `os.path.dirname` on that result.

Comment: Where are you running the code? In the REPL? It only works in a module as that is where `__file__` is defined by the import process.

Comment: spyder (Python IDE)