# Python script won't run in the current directory it's in

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to move the script to my Desktop in order for it to run. I believe this has something to do with my working path but I'm missing what that could be.

My directory structure is this:

`/dir/dir/Python/Project/script.py`

My script is very basic until I can get this basic part to work.

```
import getpass 

p = getpass.getpass()
print("You entered:", p)
```

Comment: Is your code formatted like shown. Without a line break before print?

Comment: can you run other code? Or is the `getpass` package the only thing that is not working? 
Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory), it might give some insight into your working path.

Comment: The getpass module does seem to be the only module where I have this issue. I have other scripts where I’m importing other modules and those haven’t thrown any issues yet. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my environment of `python 3.5.2` it works fine.

I guess the syntax might be a problem. Have a look at the script attached below.

```
>>> import getpass
>>> p = getpass.getpass()
Password: 
>>> print("You entered:", p)
You entered: XYZ
>>> p = getpass.getpass() print("You entered:", p)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
  p = getpass.getpass() print("You entered:", p)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please post your answer as formatted text not as an image. Also if you do not answer the question, use a comment as soon as you have enough reputation. And consider that the code was just displayed badly since the OP did not format it properly here on SO.

Comment: @KlausD. updated the answer with the text. Will keep these in mind from next time.

Comment: @SilentFlame, I'm running version 3.6.2 and the syntax works for me but only when I run the script from my Desktop directory. If I try and run it from a different directory, it throws an error and and says "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable".

Comment: @justin_0104 sorry but it run's fine on my system, I really don't know what might be the problem. If you can attach the error, I might be able to help you.