# Double backslashes for filepath_or_buffer with pd.read_csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pathlib

Python 3.6, OS Windows 7

I am trying to read a .txt using `pd.read_csv()` using relative filepath. So, from pd.read_csv() API checked out that the filepath argument can be any valid string path.

So, in order to define the relative path I use pathlib module. I have defined the relative path as:

```
df_rel_path = pathlib.Path.cwd() / ("folder1") / ("folder2") / ("file.txt")
a = str(df_rel_path)
```

Finally, I just want to use it to feed `pd.read_csv()` as:

```
df = pd.read_csv(a, engine = "python", sep = "\s+")
```

However, I am just getting an error stating "No such file or directory: ..." showing double backslashes on the folder path.

I have tried to manually write the path on pd.read_csv() using a raw string, that is, using `r"relative/path"`. However, I am still getting the same result, double backslashes. Is there something I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want by using `os` module

```
df_rel_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "folder1", "folder2"))
```

This way the `os` module will deal with the joining the path parts with the proper separator. You can omit `os.path.abspath` if you read a file that's within the same directory but I wrote it for the sake of completeness.

For more info, refer to this SO question: [Find current directory and file's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory)

Comment: I have tried but still the same results. I do not understand it. I am using the same philosophy for subprocess.Popen() and it is working perfectly.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace? Are you sure you're pointing to a proper location? Does the file truly exist?

Comment: Hi @Colonder. You were right. There was something wrong with `file.txt`. The problem was that I assumed the textfile extension was `("file.txt")` when it was not. It was `("file.out")` Nonetheless, I do not understand how using .txt extension (when it should be .out) you end up having double backslash in your paths. Thank you for your help!

Comment: On Windows, you have to use a double backslash in order to escape the \ sign

Answer (score 0):

You need a filename to call pd.read_csv. In the example 'a' is a only the path and does not point to a specific file. You could do something like this:

```
df_rel_path = pathlib.Path.cwd() / ("folder1") / ("folder2")
a = str(df_rel_path)
df = pd.read_csv(a+'/' +'filename.txt')
```

With the filename your code works for me (on Windows 10):

```
df_rel_path = pathlib.Path.cwd() / ("folder1") / ("folder2")/ ("file.txt")
a = str(df_rel_path)
df = pd.read_csv(a)
```

Comment: you are completely right. It was a mistake from my side not to specified the .txt file. But yes, I am pointing pd.read_csv() to a .txt file. I will correct the question then.