# I got a wrong directory using os.path.abspath('.')

Tags: python, python-3.x

The username of my computer is ghbjnk. 
Wherever I saved my Pyscript and ran it, I always get C:\Users\ghbjnk rather than the current working directory, why? 
I'm using VScode and Python3.0
The weird thing is, if I debug the script
Here is my Pyscript:

```html
def main():
    import os
    print(os.path.abspath('.'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: os.getcwd() also doesn't work

Comment: Are you running the program in vscode? How do you know what the CWD shoiuld be? Does it work from the command line? Basically, `os.getcwd()` is right - I mean definitively right. You just aren't where you think you are.

Comment: It's because you are running this program using the extension so you are getting the present working directory. Type `pwd` from you will get the path.

Comment: I voted to close as a dup - assuming this is an issue with configuring the vscode debugger. I have no idea why this was downvoted, though.

Comment: The current working directory you execute the script from (shown in VS Powershell terminal prompt you debug it, e.g. `PS C:\Users\Andrew`) can be different to the directory your Python script is saved. If you want to get the directory containing the Python script, you could try: `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory