# Python directory file go wrong

Tags: python, filepath, readfile, absolute-path

I am having a silly problem with reading a file in python.

I have a folder 'a' that contains my test.py and file test.json for reading.

My test.py looks like this:

```
config_path = 'test.json'
with open(config_path) as config_buffer:
    config = json.loads(config_buffer.read())
```

When I go outside the directory structure of folder 'a' and I run the command:

```
python a\test.py
```

And the console returns this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: 'test.json'
```

I try using the absolute file path using pathlib:

```
config_path = Path('end2end.json').absolute()
with open(config_path) as config_buffer:
    config = json.loads(config_buffer.read())
```

But it still returns this error to me:

```
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: 'D:\\test.json'
```

Can anyone help me to get exactly the right directory file?

Comment: try your first code, but run it from inside the directory, not from the outside

Comment: It looks like this is an issue with the "current directory".  You might find this post helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory

Comment: try 'a/test.json'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call your python script from any folder and let it access its local files without specifying paths, you can change the directory in the begining:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))

config_path = 'test.json'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you should place the `test.json` file in the current working directory.

i.e)For Example, The python file is located in `C:\users\Desktop\Code\test.py` then you should copy the file into `C:\users\Desktop\Code\`

(OR)

You should give the path of the file in `with open($PATH TO JSON FILE) as config_buffer`