# "site-packages\PIL\image.py",line 2131, in save...PermissionError:[error 13] permission denied: scr.png

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a python code that takes a screenshot and saves it. Am facing the following Error in saving a piece of code:

> ```sh
> "site-packages\PIL\image.py",line 2131, in save...PermissionError:[error 13] permission denied: scr.png
> ```

**Note**

Folder permission is set to read/write.

**Piece of code:**

```py
snapshot = ImageGrab.grab()

    # Using png because it cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG
    file = "scr.png"
    snapshot.save(file)
```

Comment: "folder permission is set to read/write." Are you certain you know which folder it's attempting to save to? Are you certain that's the folder whose permissions you checked? The [current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory) can be unintuitive.

Comment: You shouldn't be writing your image files to that directory. It's for scripts installed as part of Pillow.

Comment: It looks like you might have changed directories to run a script from that folder. If so, I suggest that you don't.  Or, use an explicit path to a directory you own.
ex: file = r'C:\Users\yourname\Documents\scr.png'
Using a r' raw string lets you use \ in the string without doubling each one.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code to desktop, then your code will automatically work.

```
Move your code out of Site-Packages to Desktop or somewhere
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in another directory and put the full path of the image file:

```
file = "path/to/img/scr.png"
```

or try with sudo or admin prompt