# How do I save a joblib dump to another folder?

Tags: python, joblib

My target structure:

- tools

  - model_maker.py
- models

  - *models go here*

My current code, which sits in the tools directory

```
joblib.dump(pipeline, "../models/model_full_June2020.jl")
```

Throws an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../models/model_full_June2020.jl'
```

I guess my path is wrong. If I remember correctly windows paths and python are different than python and other systems. When I deploy this thing to heroku, I guess it needs to work regardless of the specific system it rests on.

Comment: _My current code, which sits in the tools directory_ that doesn't mean tools is the **current directory**.

Comment: try see your current dir using 'import os; print(os.getcwd())', or seeing the path of you script when running following this [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory)

Comment: Thank you John, this set me down the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @john mentioned, this does not mean that `tools` directory is the current dir.

Set a relative path programmatically rather than assuming that your `cwd` is in the `tools` dir. You can do the following

In the file that has the script, you want to do something like this:

```
import os
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'relative/path/to/file/you/want')
joblib.dump(pipeline, filename )
```

This should correctly locate the file since the `filename` yields the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply try it. I did this for LinearRegression.

```py
joblib.dump(lr,'models/rent_lr_model')
```