# Processing 8 python processes using windows PoweShell parallel {}-section

Tags: python, windows, powershell, concurrent-processing

I have a python script that I need to run 8 times, with 8 different `.txt`-files. I'm trying to do this with a `parallel{}`-section in PowerShell.

```
workflow my_script{
  parallel {  
  python bin/script.py config/file1.txt
  python bin/script.py config/file2.txt
  python bin/script.py config/file3.txt
  python bin/script.py config/file4.txt
  python bin/script.py config/file5.txt
  python bin/script.py config/file6.txt
  python bin/script.py config/file7.txt
  python bin/script.py config/file8.txt
  } }
```

However this does not work, I'm getting the *"no such file or directory"* on `script.py`.

I'm already in the right directory, in fact if I do `python bin/script.py config/file1.txt` this works just fine.

Calling `workflow` implies that directory is changed? I don't understand why it is not running in the working directory.

Comment: Does using a full path to config files work?

Comment: Yes and no. Using the absolute path starts the script, but the script stops because it uses `sys.argv` inside the script, so it needs to be executed from the right folder. Is there a way of specifying the right starting path at the beginning of this workflow?

Comment: Workflow shouldn't change the path. Use Python's methods to [find out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5137509/503046) in which directory you end up. Maybe that will provide more clues.

Comment: Actually it is changing. Normal execution is in the current wd, when I call `workflow` it is a different dir, despite the PowerShell path is the same. My folder is in `...documents/github/folde1/folder2` while workflow starts from `...documents`

Comment: For the moment I managed it with a workaround, copying the folder I need into `documents`