# Sharing Python script that reads a .txt file on my computer

Tags: python

I have created a python script that works really well. It opens a `.txt` file and picks a word a random before using that for a quiz. If I want to share this code do I need to share the `.txt` file also and does the receiver have to change the path to the `.txt` file in the code to the location of the txt file on their computer?

Other than putting the words as a list directly in the code is there a way of referencing the `.txt` file to the code in such a way that it will work on any computer?

Comment: Make it user configurable via CLi argument -> argparse

Comment: Yes, you also need to share this .txt-file. If you put it in the same directory you can open it using _relative paths_: `./yourtextfile.txt`

Comment: if the txt file has a relative path then you will be able to access it on any computer given that it is where it should be relative to the accessing script

Comment: @OcasoProtal  not exactly, a relative path is relative *to the working directory*, this assumes that the script is run with the source code file in the working directory, but that isn't always the case

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You are correct, but for a beginner that is mostly the same directory, otherwise use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory

Comment: Thank you all for taking time to respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the hardcoded path and replacing it using a variable that will reference the file path to your text file and ask for the input when the scripts, in various ways,

1. use `input()` to ask for user input
2. read as an CLI argument that user triggers the script
3. maintain a user configuration file and have the script read it
4. ...

whatever ways you can think of that is efficient and suitable for your use case