# Get the path of the current Python file

Tags: python, file, directory, path, working-directory

I am trying to the get the path of the directory of the current running file. For example, if I the following files: `X/foo.py` and `Y/bar.py`, and I am running `python3 foo.py` and `foo.py` imports `bar.py`, and in `bar.py` I get the parent directory, I want it to be Y and not X. How do I do that? currently, I get X with  `path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()`

Comment: `bar.__file__`, or if you're in `bar`, just `__file__`

Answer (score 0):

This question already was answered here:
[Find the current directory and file's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-the-current-directory-and-files-directory)

What you need to do is the following:

```
import os 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

This will return the absolute path to the current py-file.

Comment: Please read [answer] and do not write answers for questions that "were already answered" somewhere else.