# Attempting to convert .mp3 to .wav via python subprocess call into ffmpeg, "No such file or directory" despite audio file in same directory?

Tags: python, windows, ffmpeg, subprocess

I am attempting to convert an .mp3 `testaudio.mp3` into .wav `testaudio.wav` by using Python's subprocess module and ffmpeg.

I am on Windows, and when I use command prompt to run the following command, it works and converts my .mp3 into .wav successfully:

`C:\PATH_programs\ffmpeg-4.4-full_build\ffmpeg-4.4-full_build\bin>ffmpeg -i testaudio.mp3 testaudio.wav`

However, when I attempt to use a Python script to do the same thing, I get a `"No such file or directory"` error:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'testaudio.mp3', 'testaudio.wav'])
```

The `ffmpeg.exe`, `convertmp3towav.py`, and `audiotest.mp3` files all live in the same directory `C:\PATH_programs\ffmpeg-4.4-full_build\ffmpeg-4.4-full_build\bin`.

Comment: make sure that ```testaudio.mp3``` is on the same directory of the code file.

Comment: if ```testaudio.mp3``` is in the same directory try ```.\\testaudio.mp3``` instead and the same for the output

Answer (score 0):

I think [pydub](http://pydub.com/) is more flexible than subprocess

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

audio_file = AudioSegment.from_file("testaudio.mp3")
audio_file.export("testaudio.wav", "wav")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I too have had issues with PyDub, I received `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` despite the files again being in the same directory. Question: Are these files supposed to sit in the same folder as Python is being ran from? I'm getting an impression I need to move ALL files to where `pip` installs modules like `subprocess` and `pydub` and so forth.

Comment: you can write ".\\" before the filename witch will point to the same directory of the code file

Comment: or if that didn't help, you could use `os.path` function see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-the-current-directory-and-files-directory) article to know more.