# Shortcut works however the program doesn't?

Tags: python, shortcut

The shortcut I created runs the program fine like such in the bottom right, however when I run it through VSCODE it gives me an error saying that it cannot find the file which is strange because this program worked fine both ways until I moved the file location. <<REFERENCE PICTURE FOR MORE INFO>>[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p42jO.png)

I have tried copying every type of path and modifying it in the `open('stats.txt')` however nothing works any ideas? I can post the full code if necessary however I really do not think this is a code issue.

Comment: Where is the "stats.txt" file located? Type `cd C:\path\to\folder\of\file\goes\here` in the vscode terminal and hit enter to change the current directory. That way, when the command is run and `open("stats.txt")` looks in the current directory, the current directory will have the file.

Comment: Note the difference between "current working directory" versus "location of the python file". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-the-current-directory-and-files-directory

Comment: Dennis I hope you see this, I am new to python and coding in general. When I change the code to this ```Scripts\Projects\Stock Project\Stock Related\stats.txt``` path type it will work in VSCODE but then my shortcut stops working. It worked previously in both "terminals"? should I just leave it so the shortcut works since that is what I need? or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Either (1) use the trick from the link I sent involving `__file__` to look for files in the same directory as the `.py` file, or (2) reconfigure your shortcut (go to "properties" > "start in...") to open the correct path as the current working directory.