# Why is the code giving a NameError when trying to taking user input for a file name and then reading from that file

Tags: python, user-input, readfile, read-data

the following Python code is to prompt user to specify a file name (which is stored in the variable 'file_name') and then read data from the file.

```
file_name = input("Enter the file name: ")

# Open the file and read the data
with open(file_name, "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
```

When i run this and provide a file name, it gives a FileNotFoundError. The file I am using is in the same folder as the .py file so why is it not recognising the file? am i missing something?

I have tried moving the file to several locations such as the C: root directory but it still does not recognise it

Comment: We need to know: the exact location of the file, the exact stacktrace, the exact value of the variable "file_name".

Comment: *"The file I am using is in the same folder as the .py file so why is it not recognising the file?"* Python doesn't look in the same folder as the script file, it looks in the working directory of the process, which you can check using `os.getcwd()`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-the-current-directory-and-files-directory

Comment: @slothrop how do i check the cwd in vs code?

Comment: `print(os.getcwd())` in your script, so you can see exactly what directory VSCode is running it from.

Comment: @slothrop insert that into my code? I did that and it gave a NameError saying 'os' is not defined. I dont have a script separate from that

Comment: Add a line `import os` at the start of your script to use functions from the `os` module

Comment: @slothrop it worked, but my cwd is the directory where my file is located and it still doesnt recognise it

Comment: OK that's weird - what's your cwd, what's the filename and what's the exact error?

Comment: @slothrop cwd: C:\Users\hello\Documents\Computer Science\data analysis practice filename: prec_data 
Error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'prec_data'

Comment: Thanks, and the filename is literally only `prec_data` ? With no file extension?

Comment: @slothrop sorry it was .pre. I was doing .txt, which it was originally so that was the mistake. it is fixed now, but there is another error, will try and work through it right now

Comment: OK, one problem solved at least, good luck!