# ModuleNotFoundError when python class is moved to a subdirectory

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following directory structure in my python project

[image]

When I try to execute the test_market_rates.py file I get an Module not found error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

But if I move the test_market_rates.py file to the main directory it will work without any errors

[image]

The following is how I have imported the module in test_market_rates.py file

```
from lib.utils import say_hello

print(say_hello())
```

Comment: Thanks for the question. A few follow-ups:

Comment: Have you checked for duplicates? If so, could you link them in, and why they don't answer your question.

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: From which folder do you run your script? `project_root`, or `project_root/test/test_market_rates`

Comment: im running it from project_root/test/test_market_rates

Comment: I'm using Python version 3.10.11 and I checked for duplicates but I couldn't figure out what the issue was

Answer (score 0):

### **Answer:**

There might be related questions and answers.

For this particular problem, these are three possible solutions.

Assuming the following folder structure:

```
project_root/
   lib/
      utils.py
   tests/
      test_market_rates/
          test_market_rates.py
```

### **Solution 1: Run file from Root Folder**

Run the script from `project_root`. I.e.:

`In Terminal (e.g. bash)`

```
> pwd
~/project_root
> python3 tests/test_market_rates/test_market_rates.py
Hello World!
```

### **Solution 2: Create a proper package out of "lib"**

Make a package out of `lib`.
I.e. make it "pip installable", so that you can run `pip install -e .` (local install). Then you will be able to call this file from both:
`project_root` & `tests/test_market_rates`

E.g.: https://betterscientificsoftware.github.io/python-for-hpc/tutorials/python-pypi-packaging/

In general, search for: "how to create a python package".

### **Solution 3: Add Relative Paths (Not Good Practice).**

To the file `test_market_rates.py` add the following lines of code (before the lib import statement).

```
import sys
import os
FILE_DIRECTORY=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) #path to test_market_rates.py
sys.path.append(os.path.join(FILE_DIRECTORY,"..","..")) #adds to PATH

from lib.utils import say_hello
```

You will be able to call this file from both:
`project_root` & `tests/test_market_rates`

Reference: [Find the current directory and file's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-the-current-directory-and-files-directory)

Comment: @Nimesh did the soluton work for you?