# Why can't I use __file__ in Spyder?

Tags: python, spyder

I want to get the directory that my current .py file is saved in so that I can set the current working directory to this directory programmatically. Like:

```
import os
file_path = ???
os.chdir( file_path )
```

I thought you could use `__file__` to achieve this, but it says `name '__file__' is not defined`.

Comment: In Python 2.7, you can use `os.path.abspath(__file__)` to get the absolute path of the current .py file, and then use `os.path.dirname()` to extract the directory containing the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the current directory and file's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-the-current-directory-and-files-directory)

Comment: @IshaanAdarsh This does not seem to be working: `name '__file__` is not defined. I am using Anaconda and Spyder by the way.

Comment: Then you have a different problem. `__file__` is only defined if you execute a file as a script. But there is no difference between Python 2 and 3 here.

Comment: @mkrieger1 oh I understand what is going on. I was running the code as a cell and this caused `__file__` to not work

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion Try using `os.path.realpath` not `os.path.abspath`. The error eften occurs with abspath

Comment: Just making sure: You know that Python 2 is dead (unsupported) since the beginning of 2020? That was announced 10 years before that date. Do you really have software that couldn't be migrated to Python 3 in over 13 years?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was running the above code as a cell, not as a script. If I do this the following will work

```
import os

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```