# Know the config folder path in Python

Tags: python, linux, shared-libraries

I am creating a small application in Python that needs to read a configuration file.

I intend to save this file in a folder in `/etc` on Linux, but I would like my application to run on other operating systems.

The question is: Is there some kind of constant, variable, package, etc. that can tell me the path to the most sensible settings folder on an OS?

Comment: Which folder do you expect when running under a windows OS?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is better to locate your configuration file(s) in a folder related to your actual module/application? Determine the location of your module might not be straight forward, but [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python) should help.

One tool which maybe useful, configparser, has a function which actually looks for configuration files in some standard locations: [RawConfigParser.read(filenames)](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.read)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no builtin constant for this, but it seems fairly easy to do it manually.
You could use [`sys.platform`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.platform)  or [`os.name`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.name) to get the OS, and then set the config folder according to this.

```
os_name = sys.platform
cfg_folder = {'linux2': '/etc', 'win32': 'folder', ...}[os_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os-file-dir .
After getting the root path you are able to select specific paths depending on the working OS.