# How to use beaker without install it?

Tags: python, beaker

Beaker is not a part of python standard library, and **I want to make my application has no dependencies rather than the python standard library itself**. To accomplish this, I download beaker and extract as a sub-package of my application.

Then, I use this:

```
import os, inspect, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('./beaker'))
import beaker.middleware
app = beaker.middleware.SessionMiddleware(bottle.app(), session_opts)
```

And get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 8, in <module>
    from kokoropy import kokoro_init
  File "/home/gofrendi/workspace/kokoropy/kokoropy/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import beaker.middleware
  File "/home/gofrendi/workspace/kokoropy/kokoropy/beaker/middleware.py", line 11, in <module>
    from beaker.cache import CacheManager
ImportError: No module named beaker.cache
```

The problem is laid on beaker.middleware line 11:

```
from beaker.cache import CacheManager
```

The interpreter cannot recognize beaker package since it is not installed
Actually I can fix that by change that line into this:

```
from cache import CacheManager
```

But by doing that, I need to modify a lot.

So, is there any way to use beaker without install it and without doing too many modification?

**PS:** Below is my directory structure

```
kokoropy
  |
  |--- __init__.py <-- this is where I write my script
  |
  |--- beaker
        |
        |--- __init__.py
```

**EDIT:** The accepted answer is correct, but in my case, I run the script at one-level top directory. Therefore, below solution seems to be more robust:

```
import os, inspect, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Or maybe this: [How do I get the path of the current executed file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python) :)

Comment: Copying Beaker one level down the file hierarchy maybe fixes the problem. So that you have `/home/gofrendi/workspace/kokoropy/beaker/middleware.py`. Basically treat beaker like a regular package of your application.

Comment: Actually, my directory structure is already like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the directory that contains the `beaker` directory
to the path not the beaker directory itself:

```
<root>
  |
  --beaker
      |
      -- <...>
```

In this case you need to add the `<root>` directory to the path.

According to your example code this would be:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('.'))
```

Which probably means that you run your program from this folder,
which would add it to the `PYTHONPATH` automatically.
(So it should run without you modifying the `PYTHONPATH` at all).

EDIT:

For more information on the topic you can checkout the Python docs about modules:
[Modules in python](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: I've try your suggestion, but the error is still the same. I still wonder what's wrong

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are right :p. I run the script from a one level directory above <root>. By using __files__ it works as expected

Comment: @goFrendiAsgard Ah good - I just created a test-directory structure (I don't have beaker accessible right now) and it worked, so I was really irritated that it did not work in your case. Glad that it worked out.