# python NameError: global name '__file__' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

When I run this code in python 2.7, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pyutilib.subprocess-3.5.4\setup.py", line 30, in <module>
    long_description = read('README.txt'),
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pyutilib.subprocess-3.5.4\setup.py", line 19, in read
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *rnames)).read()
NameError: global name '__file__' is not defined
```

code is:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup


def read(*rnames):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *rnames)).read()


setup(name="pyutilib.subprocess",
    version='3.5.4',
    maintainer='William E. Hart',
    maintainer_email='wehart@sandia.gov',
    url = 'https://software.sandia.gov/svn/public/pyutilib/pyutilib.subprocess',
    license = 'BSD',
    platforms = ["any"],
    description = 'PyUtilib utilites for managing subprocesses.',
    long_description = read('README.txt'),
    classifiers = [
        'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
        'Intended Audience :: End Users/Desktop',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows',
        'Operating System :: Unix',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Unix Shell',
        'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Mathematics',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules'],
      packages=['pyutilib', 'pyutilib.subprocess', 'pyutilib.subprocess.tests'],
      keywords=['utility'],
      namespace_packages=['pyutilib'],
      install_requires=['pyutilib.common', 'pyutilib.services']
      )
```

Answer (score 190):

This error comes when you append this line `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))` in python interactive shell.

`Python Shell` doesn't detect current file path in `__file__` and it's related to your `filepath` in which you added this line

So you should write this line `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))` in `file.py`. and then run `python file.py`, It works because it takes your filepath.

Comment: exactly my experience. but how to get it to work within a shell?

Comment: But to run `file.py` from a script, you would put it in the same directory as your script for example. So you need to move to this directory before running `file.py`... So still something better is sought.

Comment: So Emacs uses an interactive shell when you C-c C-p? python-shell. Is there a way to use this shell as if it were a terminal running the file?
There are 3 options for running the shell : CMD DEDICATED SHOW
Would one of them do this?

Comment: So this is not an answer for setuptools because if you distribute your package and use build with twine as pypi.org directs then none of this answer is helpful because the `setup.py` will be copied and executed in a virtualenv and no longer be able to relatively find the orphan files

Answer (score 41):

I had the same problem with PyInstaller and Py2exe so I came across the resolution on the FAQ from cx-freeze.

When using your script from the console or as an application, the functions hereunder will deliver you the "execution path", not the "actual file path":

```
print(os.getcwd())
print(sys.argv[0])
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__')))
```

Source:
http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html

Your old line (initial question):

```
def read(*rnames):
return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *rnames)).read()
```

Substitute your line of code with the following snippet.

```
def find_data_file(filename):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # The application is frozen
        datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        # The application is not frozen
        # Change this bit to match where you store your data files:
        datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    return os.path.join(datadir, filename)
```

With the above code you could add your application to the path of your os, you could execute it anywhere without the problem that your app is unable to find it's data/configuration files.

Tested with python:

- 3.3.4
- 2.7.13

Comment: `os.path.realpath('__file__')` doesn't work because it's between quotes. the rest of the answer is good

Comment: for me `os.path.realpath('__file__')` or `os.path.abspath('__file__')` do work only if `_file_` is between quotes. @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: what happens is that `realpath` doesn't check if `"__file__"` exists, it just returns current dir + "/__file__" without checking anything, so this is as good as `os.getcwd()` when `__file__` isn't defined. The real solution is to use `sys.executable` on the main python file as the rest of the answer explains

Answer (score 28):

I've run into cases where `__file__` doesn't work as expected. But the following hasn't failed me so far:

```py
import inspect
src_file_path = inspect.getfile(lambda: None)
```

This is the closest thing to a Python analog to C's `__FILE__`.

The behavior of Python's `__file__` is much different than C's `__FILE__`. The C version will give you the original path of the source file. This is useful in logging errors and knowing which source file has the bug.

Python's `__file__` only gives you the name of the currently executing file, which may not be very useful in log output.

Comment: This worksforme also when python is embedded in another application

Comment: I've had better luck with this than the `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(...))` method.

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Comment: Can't get it work with Cython with Python 2.7
```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 419, in getfile
    'function, traceback, frame, or code object'.format(object))
TypeError: <cyfunction <lambda> at 0xb6663e30> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object
```

Answer (score 22):

change your codes as follows! it works for me.
`

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("__file__"))
```

Comment: I think you are actually using `os.getcwd()`, according to [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath), and the `"__file__"` is meaningless.

Comment: Why does this have upvotes? That many people took this, and because it got rid of an unhandled exception, they assumed it was correct?? **This is not a correct solution people**. What it's doing is saying that you have a file named literally, "`__file__`" and you prepend what folder it could be in **if it existed!**

Comment: This, apparently, works because iPython fails to find `os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( os.getcwd() + "\_file_"))` and shortens it to just `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: This code wasn't tested in the same context...that's why it didn't produce the same error

Answer (score 16):

If you're using the code inside a .py file: Use
`os.path.abspath(__file__)`
If you're using the code on a script directly or in Jupyter Notebooks:
Put the **file** inside double-quotes.
`os.path.abspath("__file__")`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 10):

Are you using the interactive interpreter? You can use

```
sys.argv[0]
```

You should read: [How do I get the path of the current executed file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python)

Comment: fd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) nd printing it printed .../../folder1/ but cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
>>> print cwd prints ../../

Comment: this will give the path to the binary python that launched the shell, NOT the current working directory

Comment: it should be `argv[1]` instead of `argv[0]`

Answer (score 9):

If all you are looking for is to get your current working directory `os.getcwd()` will give you the same thing as `os.path.dirname(__file__)` as long as you have not changed the working directory elsewhere in your code.  `os.getcwd()` also works in interactive mode.

So
    `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))`
becomes
    `os.path.join(os.getcwd())`

Comment: This is a winner

Comment: This answer **isn't correct**. `os.path.dirname(__file__)` doesn't report the same thing as `os.getcwd()`. What it gives you is the dir name of the file. If that turns out to match `os.getcwd()` it's merely a coincidence.

Answer (score 7):

You will get this if you are running the commands from the python shell:

```
>>> __file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

You need to execute the file directly, by passing it in as an argument to the `python` command:

```
$ python somefile.py
```

In your case, it should really be `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 3):

If you're exec'ing a file via command line, you can use this hack

```
import traceback

def get_this_filename():
    try:
        raise NotImplementedError("No error")
    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        filename = traceback.extract_tb(exc_traceback)[-1].filename
    return filename
```

This worked for me in the UnrealEnginePython console, calling `py.exec myfile.py`

Answer (score 2):

if you are using jupyter notebook like:

MODEL_NAME = os.path.basename(**file**)[:-3]

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-f391bbbab00d> in <module>
----> 1 MODEL_NAME = os.path.basename(__file__)[:-3]

NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

you should place a ' ! ' in front like this

```
!MODEL_NAME = os.path.basename(__file__)[:-3]

/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `MODEL_NAME = os.path.basename(__file__)[:-3]'
```

done.....

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exacty the same problem and using probably [the same tutorial](http://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html). The function definition:

```
def read(*rnames):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *rnames)).read()
```

is buggy, since `os.path.dirname(__file__)` will not return what you need. Try replacing `os.path.dirname(__file__)` with `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`:

```
def read(*rnames):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), *rnames)).read()
```

I've just posted Andrew that the code snippet in current docs don't work, hopefully, it'll be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this which get your local file path

```
if not os.path.isdir(f_dir):
    os.mkdirs(f_dir)

try:
    approot = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
except NameError:
    approot = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1]))
    my_dir= os.path.join(approot, 'f_dir')
```

Answer (score 0):

Working in a jupyter notebook it is convenient to set a workspace according to the script you are working on:

```
import os
import sys
os.chdir(Path(os.path.realpath('__file__')).parents[0])
sys.path.append(Path(os.path.realpath('__file__')).parents[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) built-in function can be used to test the condition:

```
if "__file__" in globals():
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(globals()["__file__"])
```

Or if `__file__` really needs to be set to some value:

```
if "__file__" not in globals():
    __file__ = "/maybe/it/is/here.py"
```

however, I don't recommend this, as it can lead to unexpected outcomes with interactive sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can help someone using cx-freeze:

Considering this build:

```
cxfreeze -c app.py --target-dir dist --target-name="app_name.exe" --icon=icon.png
```

Consider in your app.py header this:

```
import os

DIST_PATH=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
os.chdir(DIST_PATH)
APP_PATH=os.path.dirname(DIST_PATH)
```

Explanation:
The executable is not going to be inside the app.py root folder but inside a child folder "dist"

Answer (score -1):

import traceback
def get_this_folder():
try:
raise NotImplementedError("No error")
except Exception as e:
exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
filename = traceback.extract_tb(exc_traceback)
filename=filename[0][0]
folder=os.path.dirname(str(filename))
return folder
folder=get_this_folder()
print(folder)