# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named in python 3 even after hacking sys.path()

Tags: python-3.x

I have this file structure:

```
/home/test
         ├── dirA
         │   └── ClassA.py
         └── dirB
             └── Main.py
```

With the following content in the files:

**ClassA.py**:

```
class ClassA:
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Hi'
```

**Main.py**:

```
from dirA.ClassA import ClassA

class Main:

    def main():
        a = ClassA()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main.main()
```

I change the current dir to:

```
$ cd /home/test/dirB
```

This works:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/home/test python Main.py
```

This doesn't:

```
$ python Main.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dirA.ClassA import ClassA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dirA'
```

Adding this lines in Main.py has no effect:

```
import os, sys
# Get the top level dir.
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)) 
sys.path.append(path)
```

The module still can't be found! There are plenty of similar questions but I couldn't make this work programmatically (skipping the `PYTHONPATH` env var.) I understand that dirs are not modules, files are but this works in PyCharm (is the IDE fixing `PYTHONPATH`?)

Comment: Are you adding `os.path.append(path)` before or after you call `from dirA.ClassA import ClassA`?

Comment: Before. I inserted it between the `if` and the call to `Main.main()`.

Comment: Oh, I am getting your question. You are saying `from ...` is called even before the Class instance invocation?

Comment: Yes. You need to alter your `sys.path` **before** you attempt to import anything that might depend on that path. Whether you're calling something from the imported file is inconsequential - the import itself will fail much before that.

Comment: I tried to put it on top and check that it's call with the debugger before the `from` import. It still doesn't work .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure that you've altered your `sys.path` before you attempt to load any package that might depend on the altered path - otherwise your script will fail the moment it encounters and `import` statement. In other words, make sure your `Main.py` begins as:

```
import os
import sys

path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir)
sys.path.append(path)

from dirA.ClassA import ClassA
```

To ensure that the last import statement operates on the altered path.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help. Per suggestion, I added the appended path as the first statement. That still didn't work. But then I used:

```
sys.path.append(sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))))
```

And this suddenly worked. Still not sure why the abspath makes a difference as the printed path I got was already absolute for `__file__`.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer given by @zwer, we need to check if the script is being run in interactive mode or not. If it is, then we can use the approach mentioned by @zwer. If it is not, we can use the hard coded way (which is not always foolproof.

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771894/python-nameerror-global-name-file-is-not-defined
if '__file__' in vars():
    print("We are running the script non interactively")
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir)
    sys.path.append(path)    
else:
    print('We are running the script interactively')
    sys.path.append("..")
```