# Bad:Can't finish "os.path.dirname(__file)" in ubuntu (python)(google cloud speech)

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-cloud-speech

thanks for helping me!

I just set up ***google cloud speech*** and tried to run the code in "Make an audio transcription request" in this website: [Quickstart: Using Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-python)

the code is shown below after I open ubuntu terminal:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/luffy/Lumariatuan-xxxxxxxxxxxx.json"

python

import io

import os

from google.cloud import speech

from google.cloud.speech import enums

from google.cloud.speech import types

client = speech.SpeechClient()

# The name of the audio file to transcribe

file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
        'resources',
        'audio.raw')
```

However, when I run the last part `os.path.dirname(__file)` in ***Ubuntu 18.04 terminal in python***, the error happens like below:

*** NameError: name '__file__' is not defined***

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Can you see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771894/python-nameerror-global-name-file-is-not-defined#20510502) . `__file__` needs to be in a file

Comment: you can't do this in terminal, try to use it in .py file

Comment: Thank you @MadhanM and @dilkash!
I put all the code in a .py file, and I solve the problem! However, another problem occurs when I keep running the code. Could you halp me look at it? Thanks! It's here: [Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51586920/bad-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @MadhanM or @ dilkash could you please post your comment as an answer so it can be accepted by LUHuang?

Answer (score 0):

The **file** variable contains the path to the file that Python is currently importing. You can use this variable inside a module to find the path of the module. It'll not work with an interactive python terminal.