# Bad: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, file

I use ubuntu and python to run google cloud speech. First I put all the code in a file called `lu.py` :

```
 import io
 import os
 from google.cloud import speech
...

# The name of the audio file to transcribe
file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'resources',
    'audio.raw')

# Loads the audio into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()
    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)
...
```

When I ran `python lu.py` in terminal, it said

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'resources/audio.raw'
```

I'm not familiar with the path problem, so I don't know where is wrong.

Comment: Where is your `audio.raw` file ?

Comment: Let say directory where you `lu.py` resides is `dir1` then your audio files should be in `dir1\resources\audio.raw`

Comment: Thank you ARMAN and saurabh baid! The saurabh's answer is correct! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

means file that contains the name audio.raw was not found in the path resources/[filename]

You can set the path name in the block below this comment:

```
# The name of the audio file to transcribe
```