# How do I get the current file path in python dm-script

Tags: python, filepath, dm-script

I want to get the file path of the current file in *Digital Micrograph* in `python`. How do I do this?

---

I tried to use

```py
__file__
```

but I get `NameError: Name not found globally.`

I tried to use the `dm-script` `GetCurrentScriptSourceFilePath()` with the following code to get the value to python

```py
import DigitalMicrograph as DM
import time
    
# get the __file__ by executing dm-scripts GetCurrentScriptSourceFilePath()
# function, then save the value in the persistent tags and delete the key
# again
tag = "__python__file__{}".format(round(time.time() * 100))
DM.ExecuteScriptString(
    "String __file__;\n" + 
    "GetCurrentScriptSourceFilePath(__file__);\n" + 
    "number i = GetPersistentTagGroup().TagGroupCreateNewLabeledTag(\"" + tag + "\");\n" + 
    "GetPersistentTagGroup().TagGroupSetIndexedTagAsString(i, __file__);\n"
);
_, __file__ = DM.GetPersistentTagGroup().GetTagAsString(tag);
DM.ExecuteScriptString("GetPersistentTagGroup().TagGroupDeleteTagWithLabel(\"" + tag + "\");")
```

but it seems that the `GetCurrentScriptSourceFilePath()` function does not contain a path (which makes sense because it is executed from a string).

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53293924/5934316) recommending

```py
import inspect
src_file_path = inspect.getfile(lambda: None)
```

but the `src_file_path` is `"<string>"` which is obviously wrong.

I tried to raise an exception and then get the filename of it with the following code

```py
try:
    raise Exception("No error")
except Exception as e:
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    filename = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
    print("File: ", filename)
```

but again I get `<string>` as the `filename`.

I tried to get the path out of the script window but I could not find any function to get it. But the script window has to know where its path is, otherwise <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> cannot work.

---

**Some background**

I am developing a module used for Digital Micrograph. There I also have test files. But to import the (still developed) module in the test file(s), I need the path relative to the test file.

Later the module will be installed somewhere so this should not be a problem then. But for offering a compelte set of tests, I want to be able to execute the tests without having to install the (not working) module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DM-script, which you could call from a Python script, the command `GetApplicationDirectory()` gives you what you need. Usually, you would want to use the "open_save" one, i.e.

```
GetApplicationDirectory("open_save",0)
```

This will return the directory (String variable) that appears when File/Open is used, or File/Save is used on a new image. It is, however, not what is used on a "File/Save Workspace" or other saves.

From the F1 help documentation on that command:
[image]

Note, that the concept of "current" directory is somewhat broken on Win10 with applications - including GMS.In particular the "SetApplicationDirectory" commands do not always work as expected...

---

If you want to find out what the folder of a specific, currently shown document is (image or text) you can use the following DM-script. The assumption here is, that the window is the front-most window.

```
documentwindow win = GetDocumentWindow(0)
if ( win.WindowIsvalid() )
    if ( win.WindowIsLinkedToFile() )
        Result("\n" + win.WindowGetCurrentFile())
```

Comment: So for testing this is enough for me. For others: Note that as soon as you save another file, the "open_save" directory changes to this directory!

Comment: @miile7 Well, you could use one of the other "default" directories from the list instead...

Comment: I need exactly the directory where the executing script file is in because in the same directory there are other python files which i need to import.

Comment: ( But also: Just save your script file in any of those locations, i.e. the plugins-folder f.e.. Or a subfolder or relative path to any of those...)

Comment: That sounds very promising. I will try it out tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

For the file path to your current working directory, use:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

Comment: Great idea, I forgot that. But unfortunately they are not equal, I just tested it :(

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who also needs this (and just wants to copy some code) I created the following code based on @BmyGuests answer. This takes the file the script window is bound to and saves it as a persistent tag. This tag is then read from the python file (and the tag is deleted).

**Important Note**: This only works in the python script window where you press the *Execute Script* button and only if this file is saved! But from there on you probably are importing scripts which should provide the `module.__file__` attribute. This meas this **does not work for plugins/libraries**.

```py
import DigitalMicrograph as DM

# the name of the tag is used, this is deleted so it shouldn't matter anyway
file_tag_name = "__python__file__"
# the dm-script to execute, double curly brackets are used because of the 
# python format function
script = ("\n".join((
    "DocumentWindow win = GetDocumentWindow(0);",
    "if(win.WindowIsvalid()){{",
        "if(win.WindowIsLinkedToFile()){{",
            "TagGroup tg = GetPersistentTagGroup();",
            "if(!tg.TagGroupDoesTagExist(\"{tag_name}\")){{",
                "number index = tg.TagGroupCreateNewLabeledTag(\"{tag_name}\");",
                "tg.TagGroupSetIndexedTagAsString(index, win.WindowGetCurrentFile());",
            "}}",
            "else{{",
                "tg.TagGroupSetTagAsString(\"{tag_name}\", win.WindowGetCurrentFile());",
            "}}",
        "}}",
    "}}"
))).format(tag_name=file_tag_name)

# execute the dm script
DM.ExecuteScriptString(script)

# read from the global tags to get the value to the python script
global_tags = DM.GetPersistentTagGroup()
if global_tags.IsValid():
    s, __file__ = global_tags.GetTagAsString(file_tag_name);
    if s:
        # delete the created tag again
        DM.ExecuteScriptString(
            "GetPersistentTagGroup()." + 
            "TagGroupDeleteTagWithLabel(\"{}\");".format(file_tag_name)
        )
    else:
        del __file__

try:
    __file__
except NameError:
    # set a default if the __file__ could not be received
    __file__ = ""
    
print(__file__);
```