# Resolve path of .py and .ipynb file for sphinx-gallery build and pytest

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pathlib

[Sphinx-gallery](https://sphinx-gallery.github.io/stable/index.html) offers the option to create `.py` files that can be generated into `.ipynb` files and directly execute them for documentation.

I have the following file structure:

```
Project/
|--doc
|  |--Makefile
| 
|--examples
|  |--data
|  |--plot_example_1.py
|  
|--tests
|  |--test_run_examples.py
```

In `plot_example_1.py` I now want to read the example data stored in `data`, and therefore require the path of the current directory.
When first generating the documentation I can resolve it with

```
from pathlib import Path

Path().resolve()
```

I want to test the examples however additionally using `pytest`. This fails when calling `pytest tests` from the root directory.

Instead I could succesfully test it when adapting the path call to `Path(__file__).absolute()`, but the `__file__` option is not available in the `ipynb` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771894/python-nameerror-global-name-file-is-not-defined)

So I need an option that can resolve the path for both the python file and ipynb. Is there any option for that?

Answer (score 0):

A simple option would be to pass the absolute pass with `pytest` to the module, and then check if the `argv` has that parameter.

Otherwise a potential option is to shift the `data` folder in the main project directory and load it from there:

```
import project_name
Path(project_name.__file__).parent / "data"
```

Of course with the trade-off that the data needs to be installed with the main package. Hopefully there is a better solution in future.

@larsoner provided an answer [here](https://github.com/sphinx-gallery/sphinx-gallery/issues/1168#issuecomment-1680605592)