# Current path of a program differs when run localy and when run on server

Tags: python, django, apache

i have a django web that on certain actions is calling a .exe on the server using this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([r'C:/.../django/project/app/program.exe', 'arg1', 'arg2', ..], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
s = proc.stdout.read()
proc.wait()
```

The problem is that program.exe, in turn, has to open some files on the server. This files are called by the code (in c++) using relative path, and are stored at the same folder where the .exe is. When I run program.exe from the IDE or the terminal it works like a charm, but not when it is at the server.

I have done a simple program in c++and placed it at the same folder as program.exe to know what is the current path when program.exe is run at the server:

```
#define GetCurrentDir _getcwd
int main(int argc, char* argv[]{
    char cCurrentPath[FILENAME_MAX];
    GetCurrentDir(cCurrentPath, sizeof(cCurrentPath));
    std::cout << cCurrentPath << std::endl;
}
```

And in state of returning C:/.../django/project/app, it returns C:/.../django/project. I know I can set the path of the files relative to cCurrentPath, but is there any other way to do it, by changing the server configuration?

I am using 2 different servers, apache and the django development server on windows.

Comment: It's unclear what you are actually asking. Is this an answer to your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python

Comment: check if doing os.chdir('path-to-your-required-dir') before subprocess open call helps