# File path relative to where it was imported

Tags: python, package, directory-structure

I have:

```
project
|--__init__.py
|--...
+--package1
|  |--__init__.py
|  |--...
+--dbs
   |--...
```

Where `project` is a collection of packages to be imported and used by the user. The names are just an example.

Now, some files under `project/package1/` need to access some files in `project/dbs/`, but depending on where the user placed the `project` folder and from where he or she imported it, `path/to/project/dbs/file` is not the same. Because of this issue and for other purposes I thought I should have a variable `projectroot` defined as the root of the project, relative to where it was imported from. For instance:

If the user has `~/Desktop/project` and imported it from `~/` then `projectroot` would be `Desktop/project`, and `path/to/project/dbs/file` would be `"%s/dbs/file" % (projectroot)`. Is this really needed? If so, what is the best way of doing it?

---

I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2632297) in `project/pathtfinder.py` and used `project/__init__.py` as

```
import pathfinder
projectroot=pathfinder.module_path()
import package1
```

But when I run `import project` I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "project/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import package1
  File "project/package1/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    db = sqlite3.connect("%s/dbs/main.db" % projectroot)
  NameError: name 'projectroot' is not defined
```

And if use `print projectroot` just after defining it I get `Desktop/project`, as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the path of project to the PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0):

This is a pattern I use for my Flask apps, but the same should be ideal for you:

Assume the following is in a file under `helloworld/app.py`

```
import sys
import os
# Add this app to the path so imports work as expected
APP_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../')
sys.path.append(APP_PATH)

from helloworld.utils import a_utility
```

The convention explains itself, but it allows for the imports to occur from the "root" of the project, regardless of where the file is placed. You'll want to place that APP_PATH code perhaps in your **init**.py, or similar.