# how to os.mkdir() above current root path in python

Tags: python, path, flask, mkdir

i am running a flask project and i am looking for a way to create a directory ABOVE the path from which the current App is running. For example:

```
dirA -->
    dirBinA -->
        peter.py
        griffin.sh
    dirCinA -->
        index.py <--------- this is the flask app that's running
        tom.css
        dick.html
        harry.js
    dirDinA -->  <--------- this directory doesn't exist yet
        anotherDir -->
            turtle.py
```

i want to create a new directory `anotherDir` inside a new directory `dirDinA` from the flask app that's running in `dirCinA/index.py`

If I try with `os.mkdir("../dirDinA/anotherDir/")`, then flask says `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../dirDinA/anotherDir'`

Comment: The current directory is not the directory of the file that is executing. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: @user2246674, you are correct... the starting '/' was a typo from my end... very sorry for that.. i am correcting the question

Comment: @syedrakib Might find useful information in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python

Comment: i must apologize to everyone... while writing the question i ignored some of the original cases for which the error was actually being produced... i have corrected the question appropriately... please accept my apologies for the mis-understandings created... thanks to everyone for the helpful comments posted here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a new 2-level-depth directory, you need to create it in ***TWO*** steps. For instance, if `../dirDinA` doesn't yet exist, then the following command fails.

```
os.mkdir("../dirDinA/anotherDir")
```

It produces the `OSError: No such file or directory`, misleadingly, showing you the ***FULL*** path that you are trying to create, instead of highlighting on the ***ACTUAL*** part whose non-existence is producing the error.

However, the following 2 step method goes well without any error

```
os.mkdir("../dirDinA")
os.mkdir("../dirDinA/anotherDir")
```

Directory `../dirDinA` needs to exist before `anotherDir` can be created inside it

Thanks goes to the [answer by @JimPivarski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16868483/636762).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=makedir#os.makedirs) to create multiple directory levels in a single call:

```
os.makedirs("../dirDinA/anotherDir")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're running the Python script in the intended directory, you need to create a new directory and put things in it in two steps.  For instance, if `../dirDinA` does not exist, then

```
os.mkdir("../dirDinA/a_new_file.py")
```

produces the "No such file or directory" error (and misleadingly shows you the full path that you want to make, not the part whose non-existence is causing the problem).  The following

```
os.mkdir("../dirDinA")
open("../dirDinA/a_new_file.py", "w").write("test")
```

does not produce an error.

Comment: Thanks @Jim Pivarski... your answer was helpful for my problem... i have corrected my question a little bit and, hence, i have edited this answer as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use os.popen:

```
os.popen("cd ..; mkdir dirDinA; mkdir ./dirDinA/anotherDir; --code for creating turtle.py--; chmod +x turtle.py; python turtle.py");
```

Hope it helpful for you.