# How do I import from a relative path?

Tags: python

I am posting this because the answers to this question ([Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-folder)) are not usable for those of us likely to be asking the question in the first place.

Suppose I have the following file structure (I have kept the same naming convention from the other question):

```
C:\dirMain\
     dirFoo\
        Foo.py
     dirBar\
        Bar.py
```

I want to import `Bar.py` from within `Foo.py`.

Something like this: (My C is showing here, sorry):

```
# Foo.py
from ../dirBar/Bar import *
```

Please feel free to mark as a duplicate but do check the other responses first; most of the ones I have seen are overly complicated, don't work, or are incomplete. This is a simple question for which there is hopefully a simple answer.

Things I've tried:

1) The suggestion below from Puffin GDI:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
```

result:

> NameError: name '**file**' is not defined

The solution to this ostensibly lies amidst [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python), where I do not know.

2) This from here: [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

```
import imp
abc = imp.load_source('bar.py', 'C:\dirMain\dirBar.py')
```

result:

> IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid Argument

3) As discussed here: [Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-folder)

(first added `__init__.py` to `/dirBar`)

```
from ..dirBar import Bar
```

result:

> ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Comment: Look back over those duplicates.  The answer is, basically, you can't directly import relative to the directory structure.  You can only import relatively *within packages*, which means you must add `__init__.py` files to each subdirectory to make them packages.

Comment: @BrenBarn, I've tried creating that file, but then what?

Comment: Then you do `from ..dirBar import Bar`, as discussed in all those duplicate questions.  You must also have `__init__.py` in `dirMain` and the directory containing `dirMain` must be on the Python library path, as also discussed in all those duplicate questions.

Comment: @BrenBarn I just get the error "ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package"

Comment: @ausainman: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py/11537218#11537218) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/python-relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132912#14132912), just two among many of the zillion duplicates of which you are already aware.

Comment: @BrenBarn well I have read those but they are either a) solutions that don't work b) essays on what a module is or c) too complicated for me to understand. I have been writing C++ for years so I like to think I'm capable of comprehending this stuff, but I seem to be mistaken!

Comment: @BrenBarn maybe something useful for me to know would be what exactly a python programmer does when he has functions used by files in different folders. Does he make lots of copies?

Comment: That is maybe a good question to ask on its own.  What I'd say is, if `Foo` needs `Bar` because they're both part of one project, make them all part of a package.  If they're independent libraries, make them actual libraries in directories on the Python path.  The basic thing about Python libs is everything works based on the Python path (`sys.path`), so you're better off putting things in directories on the path --- that is, make your libraries real libraries that are globally available.  What becomes painful is if you want to import between arbitrary directories that are not on the path.

Answer (score 0):

Import your root path in your all programs. Start travel path from the root in all programs.

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
```

or

```
root = "C:\dirMain"
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), root)))
```

You can write root path in your configure, then

```
from dirBar.Bar import class_name
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'sys' is not defined`

Comment: Ok now it's `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`, am I supposed to fill that with something?

Comment: I think maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python) can help you.