# NameError: global name 'unicode' is not defined - in Python 3

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x, nameerror, bidi

I am trying to use a Python package called bidi. In a module in this package (algorithm.py) there are some lines that give me error, although it is part of the package.

Here are the lines:

```
# utf-8 ? we need unicode
if isinstance(unicode_or_str, unicode):
    text = unicode_or_str
    decoded = False
else:
    text = unicode_or_str.decode(encoding)
    decoded = True
```

and here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\python_bidi-0.3.4-py3.3.egg\bidi\algorithm.py",   line 602, in get_display
    if isinstance(unicode_or_str, unicode):
NameError: global name 'unicode' is not defined
```

How should I re-write this part of the code so it works in Python3?
Also if anyone have used bidi package with Python 3 please let me know if they have found similar problems or not. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 289, accepted):

Python 3 renamed the `unicode` type to `str`, the old `str` type has been replaced by `bytes`.

```
if isinstance(unicode_or_str, str):
    text = unicode_or_str
    decoded = False
else:
    text = unicode_or_str.decode(encoding)
    decoded = True
```

You may want to read the [Python 3 porting HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/pyporting.html) for more such details. There is also Lennart Regebro's [Porting to Python 3: An in-depth guide](http://python3porting.com/), free online.

Last but not least, you could just try to use the [`2to3` tool](http://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) to see how that translates the code for you.

Comment: So should I write: if isinstance(unicode_or_str, str)? How about 'unicode_or_str'?

Comment: The variable name doesn't much matter here; `if isinstance(unicode_or_str, str)` should just work. Renaming the variable name is optional.

Answer (score 52):

If you need to have the script keep working on python2 and 3 as I did, this might help someone

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    unicode = str
```

and can then just do for example

```
foo = unicode.lower(foo)
```

Comment: This is the right idea, nice answer. Just to add a detail, if you are using the `six` library to manage Python 2/3 compatibility, you can make this: `if six.PY3: unicode = str` instead of `sys.version_info` stuff. This is also very helpful for preventing linter errors related to unicode being undefined in Python 3, without needing special linter rule exemptions.

Answer (score 26):

You can use the [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) library to support both Python 2 and 3:

```
import six
if isinstance(value, six.string_types):
    handle_string(value)
```

Answer (score 4):

One can replace `unicode` with `u''.__class__` to handle the missing `unicode` class in Python 3. For both Python 2 and 3, you can use the construct

```
isinstance(unicode_or_str, u''.__class__)
```

or

```
type(unicode_or_str) == type(u'')
```

Depending on your further processing, consider the different outcome:

Python 3

```
>>> isinstance(u'text', u''.__class__)
True
>>> isinstance('text', u''.__class__)
True
```

Python 2

```
>>> isinstance(u'text', u''.__class__)
True
>>> isinstance('text', u''.__class__)
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are using Python 3 ,
Str are unicode by default, so please 
Replace `Unicode` function with String `Str` function.

```
if isinstance(unicode_or_str, str):    ##Replaces with str
    text = unicode_or_str
    decoded = False
```

Comment: that doesn't preserve BC like the answer from @atm

Please consider retracting or updating your answer. There is no reason to leave python2 users behind or have breaking python3

Answer (score 1):

If a 3rd-party library uses `unicode` and you can't change their source code, the following monkey patch will work to use `str` instead of `unicode` in the module:

```py
import <module>
<module>.unicode = str
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in python2 or python3

```
type(value).__name__ == 'unicode':
```