# pandas - change df.index from float64 to unicode or string

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, rows

I want to change a dataframes' index (rows) from float64 to string or unicode.

I thought this would work but apparently not:

```
#check type
type(df.index)
'pandas.core.index.Float64Index'

#change type to unicode
if not isinstance(df.index, unicode):
    df.index = df.index.astype(unicode)
```

error message:

```
TypeError: Setting <class 'pandas.core.index.Float64Index'> dtype to anything other than float64 or object is not supported
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can do it that way:

```
# for Python 2
df.index = df.index.map(unicode) 

# for Python 3 (the unicode type does not exist and is replaced by str)
df.index = df.index.map(str)
```

As for why you would proceed differently from when you'd convert from int to float, that's a peculiarity of numpy (the library on which pandas is based).

Every numpy array has a *dtype*, which is basically the **machine** type of its elements : in that manner, **numpy deals directly with native types**, not with Python objects, which explains how it is so fast. So when you are changing the dtype from int64 to float64, numpy will cast each element in the C code.

There's also a special dtype : *object*, that will basically provide a pointer toward a Python object.

If you want strings, you thus have to use the *object* dtype. But using `.astype(object)` would not give you the answer you were looking for : it would instead create an index with *object* dtype, but put Python float objects inside.

Here, by using map, we convert the index to strings with the appropriate function: numpy gets the string objects and understand that the index has to have an *object* dtype, because that's the only dtype that can accomodate strings.

Comment: This doesn't work on Python 3.5. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: The original poster was using Python 2. the `unicode` type does not exist anymore in Python 3, and the `str` type must be used instead (basically, what was called `str` in Python 2 is called `bytes` in Python 3, and `unicode` likewise became `str`).
See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877306/nameerror-global-name-unicode-is-not-defined-in-python-3) for more information.

Comment: I tried this in Python 3 and it did not change anything. I am trying to go change an index from  Object to a String.

Comment: @PMcK I got the same issue. Any success?

Answer (score 17):

For python 3 and pandas 0.19 or latter versions, I found the following works fine for me

```
# Python 3 (pandas 0.19 or latter versions)
df.index.astype(str, copy = False)
```

Comment: Sometimes `df.index = df.index.astype(int)` is needed instead of `copy=False`.

Comment: @MicheldeRuiter Could you tell me when assignment is needed instead of copy=False?

Comment: @VaM999 I don't remember... :-(

Comment: I had an issue when using copy=False and the type was np.uint64, The output would not be unsigned anymore

Comment: This doesn't work for Python 3.8/pandas 1.3.4. Both with copy=True and False. Can you recheck and confirm which versions this works in?

Answer (score 4):

For me this works the best:

```py
df.index = df.index.astype('int64')
```

where *`int64`* can be changed into other types.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).