# Python / Pandas to SQLite - ascii encoding errors

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, sqlite

One of my SQLite database tables has a publication citation field. I'm trying to update/append to the database table from a source Excel file. So, I am using pandas to bring in the Excel file, and I wrote a loop to update by row. (Note, I wrote a loop instead of using pandas '.to_sql' because on replace, it deletes the primary keys from the SQLite table.)

I am getting an error related to ascii encoding when I try to update the SQLite table. The errors are related to em-dashes, accented letters in authors' names, etc.

**How can I force some kind of ignore/replace on the encoding errors and just default to some kind of simple string?** It is not important for the citation string to be perfectly replicated in the SQL table.

The loop below works if I drop the Citations field that has the encoding issues.

```
# my variables:
# fileIn, tab, db_path
import pandas as pd, sqlite3

xls = pd.ExcelFile(fileIn)
df = xls.parse(tab)
df['Citation'] = df['Citation'].fillna(value='tbd')
df = df.drop('Citation', axis= 'columns')
# drop for now, issues with unicode characters

conn = qlite3.connect(db_path)
cur = conn.cursor()
allfields = list(df)
allfields.remove('index')
fields2 = ', '.join(str(x) for x in allfields)
cells = ['?'] * len(allfields)
cells = ', '.join(str(x) for x in cells)
str_sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + tablename + ' (' + fields2 + ') ' + 'VALUES' + ' (' + cells + ')'
for row in df.index.values:
    val = ['?'] * len(allfields)
    for ii in range(len(allfields)):
        field = allfields[ii]
        val[ii] = df.loc[row].at[field]
        # issues with unicode characters from Citations in val
    print val
    cur.executemany(str_sql, (val,))
    del val
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Also worth noting that I fixed previous type errors by putting this before my loop:

```
sqlite3.register_adapter(np.float64, float)
sqlite3.register_adapter(np.float32, float)
sqlite3.register_adapter(np.int64, int)
sqlite3.register_adapter(np.int32, int)

def adapt_datetime(datetime):
    return (datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')).encode()
sqlite3.register_adapter(dt.datetime, adapt_datetime)
sqlite3.register_adapter(dt.date, adapt_datetime)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368645/pandas-change-df-index-from-float64-to-unicode-or-string)

new code, works like a charm:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(fileIn)
df = xls.parse(tab)
df['Citation'] = df['Citation'].fillna(value='tbd')
df.Citation = df.Citation.map(unicode)
```