# How to convert pandas DataFrame to dict with string index string value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas DataFrame with 2 columns. How can I convert this into a Python dictionary with `id` as key and `name` as value?

**INPUT**

```
id | name
1  | hello
2  | world
```

**REQUIRED OUTPUT**

```
{
    "1": "hello",
    "2": "world",
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dataframe to dict such that one column is the key and the other is the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53941224/dataframe-to-dict-such-that-one-column-is-the-key-and-the-other-is-the-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
In [1256]: df.set_index('id').to_dict()['name']
Out[1256]: {1: 'hello', 2: 'world'}
```

Answer (score 2):

`zip` the two columns you want.

```
dict(zip(df['id'].astype(str), df['name']))
#{'1': 'hello', '2': 'world'}
```

If you want to use the pandas methods, make things strings then set the keys to your index and grab the column you want to be the values and go with `.to_dict`

```
(df.astype('str')
   .set_index('id')['name']
   .to_dict()
)
```

Comment: `df.astype('str')` won’t make the index values strings.

Comment: In the example both `'id'` and `'name'` are columns so it will. You can see in my second example I then set the index to be `'id'` as it's not to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
dict_ = {}
for  i , value in enumerate(df[‘name’]):
    dict_[i] = value
```

You can also try:

```
dict_ = df.set_index('id').to_dict()['name']
```

If you want dictionary value as list:

```
dict_ = df.set_index('id').T.to_dict('list')
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way without loops/enumeration?

Answer (score 1):

Let us do

```
d=dict(zip(df.id,df.name))
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers focus on the conversion from pandas DataFrame to dict, however the question is also about having the index values as strings.

[The solution for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35368792/812102) is to map the index to str beforehand :

```
df.to_dict()
{'name': {0: 'hello', 1: 'world'}}

df.index = df.index.map(str)
df.to_dict()
{'name': {'0': 'hello', '1': 'world'}}
```