# (Python) Make variable equal to zero if the data type is not numeric

Tags: python

I have this variable assignation in my code which take data from web and converts it to float (after extracting numbers only)

```
variable_1 = float(re.sub('[^0-9]','', basic_data_list[17]))
```

Now if there is no data on the web (which is specified by "-") I get the error

ValueError: could not convert string to float: which is expected.

Is there any way I can get the value zero assigned to this variable if no data is available? Is there any equivalent of Excels's IsError in python?

Comment: you can check first if the data is "-".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, for a float, you probably should accept `.` and `-` :

```
variable_1 = float(re.sub('[^0-9\-\.]','', basic_data_list[17]))
```

Otherwise :

```
float(re.sub('[^0-9]','', '-3.5'))
```

would return

```
35.0
```

Then :

```
variable_1 = float(re.sub('[^0-9\-\.]','', 'abc'))
```

raises a `ValueError`.

You could use a [try](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) block. There's even an example in the documentation which directly describes your problem :

```
>>> while True:
...     try:
...         x = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
...         break
...     except ValueError:
...         print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
```

In the `except ValueError` part, you could define `variable_1` as you wish. Note that `0` is not always the best value to assign for "not a number" :

```
try:
  variable_1 = float(re.sub('[^0-9\-\.]','', basic_data_list[17]))
except ValueError:
  variable_1 = 0.0
```

Comment: See update. Just set `variable_1 = 0` in the `except` block.

Comment: See @antonmik answer. It's a one-liner, but it's not very readable IMHO.

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful

Answer (score 2):

str.isnumeric() works on unicode strings. so if you use:

```
unicode(basic_data_list[17]).isnumeric()
```

you'll get a boolean value - True for numeric and False for non-numeric values.

so i'm thinking something along these lines will work:

```
variable_1 = float(re.sub('[^0-9]','', basic_data_list[17] if unicode(basic_data_list[17]).isnumeric() else "0"))
```

from your reply i'm guessing youre using python 3. heres what i found:
[NameError: global name 'unicode' is not defined - in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877306/nameerror-global-name-unicode-is-not-defined-in-python-3)

you should be able to use this by replacing "unicode" with "str"

Comment: It gives error -NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

Comment: You are right. I am using Python 3.6. Its works fine now. Thanks a lot to you too.