# scrapy - item loader - default processors

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to python and scrapy, so I apologise for maybe silly questions in advance. I have some troubles with default item loader's processors, and related questions:

1. I use default_input_processor variable to extract first value from list using TakeFirst() processor like that:

   ```
   class    CaseLoader(scrapy.loader.ItemLoader):
       default_input_processor = TakeFirst()
   ```

   and usage:

   ```
     def load_row_data(self, row):
         cl = CaseLoader(CaseItem(), row)

         cl.add_xpath('case_num',  './/td[1]/a/text()')
         cl.add_xpath('case_link', './/td[1]/a/@href')
         cl.add_xpath('name',      './/td[3]/text()')
         return cl.load_item()
   ```

   then I yield this item from callback methos, but TakeFirst() doesn't work, I get a list instead of string. If I use TakeFist() as default_output_processor, it works. How does default_input_processor works? Why TakeFisrt() processor isn't applied in this case?
2. In [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) I saw usage of unicode.strip method:

   ```
   from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
   from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join

   class ProductLoader(ItemLoader):

       default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

       name_in = MapCompose(unicode.title)
       name_out = Join()

       rice_in = MapCompose(unicode.strip)

       # ...
   ```

   But when I tried to use it in my Item Loader in Compose() I get error:

   ```
   NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
   ```

   If I understand right this method should remove white spaces from beginning and end of the string. How to use it properly? Do I need to code and use my strip function instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the documentation is using Python2 and you are using Python3

There is no `unicode` in Python3. You should use `str` instead

```
class ProductLoader(ItemLoader):

    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

    name_in = MapCompose(str.title)
    name_out = Join()

    rice_in = MapCompose(str.strip)
```

See below thread also for more information

[NameError: global name 'unicode' is not defined - in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877306/nameerror-global-name-unicode-is-not-defined-in-python-3)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but could you provide explanation to my first question too? If needed, I can provide more information about problem.

Comment: Because you didn't add a output processor. Add `default_output_processor = TakeFirst()` and then try

Comment: default_input_processor doesn't work without default_output_processor? I want to use another processor as default_output_processor, can I use TakeFirst() as default_input_processor, if not, why?

Comment: That is the way it is written. `if processed_value: self._values[field_name] += arg_to_iter(processed_value)`. After applying input process it is converted back to array so you can apply output processors. As processors will assume input as an array only.